# How do I run .sh scripts?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, execute-command

Whenever I open a .sh file, it opens it in gedit instead of the terminal. I can't find any option similar to **Right Click** → **Open With** → **Other Application...** → **Terminal**.

How do I open this file in the terminal?

Comment: Does that script aim to set up env variables for further use?

Comment: You shouldn't use extensions on scripts. At some point in the future, you may find that a different language is more suitable to do the task your current script is doing. And then you have a problem. Do you keep the old name, with a completely misleading extension, or do you rename it, possibly having to edit alot of places where your script is used?

Comment: You don't need the file extension. It's nice to have but is not needed. The OS doesn't look at the file extension. It looks at the data

Comment: Meh, if you rewrite foo.sh in ruby, you can always use the .sh file to launch `ruby foo.rb`

Comment: In Dolphin you can press F4 and a console opens

Comment: @ActionParsnip I was under the impression that linux would open the file and look at the header to determine what type of file it was dealing with?

Answer (score 756):

Give execute permission to your script:

```
chmod +x /path/to/yourscript.sh
```

And to run your script:

```
/path/to/yourscript.sh
```

Since `.` refers to the current directory: if `yourscript.sh` is in the current directory, you can simplify this to:

```
./yourscript.sh
```

Comment: +1 only answer to show adding execute permissions in a terminal only way.

Comment: If you do `bash /path/to/yourscript.sh` then you don't need `chmod +x`

Comment: Actually, you can use `. /path/to/yourscript.sh` if the script have to set up some environment variables.

Comment: Nobody mentions the traditional: `./path/to/yourscript.sh` (without the space after `.`)? I find that one is the simplest and easiest to use... But anyways, here is my alternative that should do almost the same as `./` would, though I don't see why you wouldn't use `./`: `(FILENAME=~/rem4space.sh;SLL=$(cat $FILENAME|head -1|sed 's:^#!\(.*\):\1:g');[ ! -z $SLL ] && exec $SLL $FILENAME;sh $FILENAME)` ... edit `FILENAME` to your liking. Also note that `sh` will be used if there is no alternative.

Comment: It required using sudo bash on GitHub workspaces

Answer (score 111):

You need to mark shell scripts as executable to run them from the file manager:

1. Right click on your `.sh` file and select *Properties*:

   [image]
2. In the *Permissions* tab, check *Allow executing file as program*:

   [image]
3. Close the *Properties* window and double-click the file. A dialog will pop up giving you the option to run the script in a terminal:

   [image]

Comment: This isn't working in Ubuntu 13.04. Keeps opening in gedit anyway, never asks me to execute. Edit: Nvm, imjustmatthew answers this.

Comment: Before using this we need to make the file permission for execute using chmod.

chmod +x filename.sh 
or
chmod 755 filename.sh

Comment: I don't have popup! IDE is opened straight away, not a popup

Comment: How come I can't find "run in terminal" anywhere on my interface? (Ubuntu 18.04)

Comment: Ok, so how do I get it to remember to automatically "Execute" (my options are a bit different than yours) so I don't have to select that every time I try to run it?  I want to just double click and have it run.

Comment: @DanielMöller, here is the answer to your question.
https://askubuntu.com/questions/38661/how-do-i-run-sh-files/1065846#1065846

Comment: If using Nautilus, or "Files" as it is currently, you must set the preferences for executable text files as described in this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/537318/159431

Answer (score 76):

Open a terminal and navigate to the folder where the `.sh` file is located.  Then type:

```
sh <name of file>.sh
```

Comment: the best way to open any application.
Navigate to .sh directory then open it in command prompt.
the use sh <name of file as shown above>.sh
if it requires permission use chmod +x /path/to/yourscript.sh 
or right click and change permission to all

Comment: This is my favored method of doing it. @DurgeshKumar nice tips.

Comment: Tried to run a sh script on alpine. While other answers did not work, this did.

Comment: how about $ sudo bash asdad.sh

Answer (score 33):

### Prerequisite

Before you can run the .sh file, you need to make it executable:

1. Right-click on the file
2. Select *Properties*
3. Select *Permissions*
4. Select *Allow executing file as a program*

### Warning

Make sure you trust the source where you got the file from. It could be a **virus**.

### The very simple way

1. Double-click on the file
2. Click run in terminal

This has problem. The terminal will close immediately and you will not be able to see the output.

### The simple way

1. Open Applications -> Accessories -> Terminal
2. Drag and drop the .sh file into the terminal and press Enter

### The way professionals do it

1. Open Applications -> Accessories -> Terminal
2. Find where the .sh file

   - Use the `ls` and `cd` commands
   - `ls` will list the files and folders in the **current folder**. Give it a try: type "ls" and press Enter.
   - Once you see the folder that you want to go in to, run `cd`, followed by a space, followed by a folder name
   - If you when into a folder that you did not want, run `cd ..` to go one level **up**
3. Run the .sh file

   - Once you can see for example `script1.sh` with `ls` run this:

     ```
     ./script.sh
     ```

### Why do it the complicated way?

The terminal has a rich set of powerful tools that are accessible by typing the commands. Professionals locate the .sh file by typing `ls` and `cd`. Once you are in the correct **current folder** you can run the script like this:

```
./script1.sh
```

or you can run and redirect the output to a file:

```
./script1.sh > out.txt
```

or you can filter the output for keywords (e.g. "apples") an then redirect to a file:

```
./script1.sh | grep apples > ./only-apples
```

There are thousands of things you can to to that file just by typing a few commands.

Another one, you can download a file from the Internet with one simple command:

```
wget www.google.com/images/logos/ps_logo2.png
```

And then open the file like this:

```
shotwell ps_logo2.png
```

Comment: Im not sure that *The way professionals do it* is correct, it's more a case of the *simple way* the *advanced(for for control of output)* way

Comment: It's good to know I did it the way professionals do it on my first trial. I thought it was the basic user's way.

Answer (score 24):

On Ubuntu 13.04 executable files opened in Nautilus are now opened in gedit by default rather than prompting the user to execute them. To enable the classic behavior you need to adjust the preferences:

Nautilus → Edit menu → Preferences → Behaviour tab → Click the radio button near Ask each time.

Comment: The person who asked the question is talking about Ubuntu 10.10

Comment: Thank you!!! I don't know why they'd change this, couldn't figure out how to execute anything.

Comment: This is the right answer for latest ubuntus.

Comment: How do you get to Nautilus in 15.10?

Comment: As of Ubuntu 18.04, you can access the preferences by opening a directory and then clicking "Files -> Preferences" in the top bar.

Answer (score 11):

For **Ubuntu 18.04**, There is a little modification, as you don't get a pop-up dialog.

So what you need to do is:

**Right click on Files, Select Preferences > Select Behavior Tab > Mark 'Ask what to do' option under Executable text file.**

Now, When you double-click on any .sh file, you will get a popup, there you can select "run in terminal" option to run your .sh file.

[image]

Comment: bit weird as I don't have the "preferences" option in right click menu. I only have properties.

Comment: For me this also made it ask for other completely unrelated extensions which is a real drag. Anyway to only make it ask this for things ending in a `.sh` extension.

Comment: +1, the same works also in 20.04

Answer (score 10):

Go to the directory where the `.sh` file is by using `cd`. In this example I have stored my `sh` file as `~/Desktop/shell_practice/test.sh`

first do `pwd` to figure out where you are, and if it returns `/home/username` (where `username` is your real username), you can run

```
cd Desktop/shell/practice
```

If you seem to be somewhere else, you can use the absolute path

```
cd ~/Desktop/shell/practice
```

or

```
cd $HOME/Desktop/shell/practice
```

or even

```
cd /home/$USER/Desktop/shell/practice
```

these are all ways of describing the same place. Once you've made it to the location of your script, type

```
ls
```

If you can see the `sh` file in the output, you can use `chmod` to make it executable. In my case, remember, the filename is `test.sh`, so I would run

```
chmod u+x test.sh
```

Now that we are in the same directory as the script, we have to specify to the shell that we want to execute the file by giving its location `./` (the current directory followed by a path separator, to distinguish it from the filename). To run my file I would type:

```
./test.sh
```

If your script has been written correctly it will run without errors...

Here's a live example:
[image: Here is live example]

Comment: This worked for me to install Netbeans on ubuntu

Comment: Wb, @RuD3B0y, i tried to keep the answers best for noobs, no high tech content, if you have some edits you are welcome.

Answer (score 7):

There are a few ways to do this.

#### Option 1

1. In the terminal, access the directory the Bash file is in using `cd` (change directory).

   Ex. `cd Downloads`
2. Run `bash <filename>.sh`

   This also works with .run files. There is an example of this usage [at this webpage on updating Rhythmbox.](http://mtweb.site90.com/tech-tos/install-rhythmbox-3-linux-ubuntu/)

#### Option 2

1. In the terminal, navigate to the directory the bash file is in.
2. Run `chmod +x <filename>.sh`
3. In Nautilus, open the file.

Answer (score 6):

2 main steps.

1. in terminal, use gedit to write and save script with ".sh" extension to desktop.
   (but any text editor can be used)
2. open Nautilus and right click the script.sh file.

   - under properties, check box "allow executing file.."
   - in Nautilus menu, click file,then preferences,then behaviour
   - check the "run executable text files when they are opened".

Now, when you double click the file on the desktop, it should execute.
no need for `.` or `./`

Answer (score 5):

1. Right-click the `.sh` file and make it executable.
2. Open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>).
3. Drag the `.sh` file into the terminal window and watch in awe.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend to [edit] this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do the first step. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on AskUbuntu.)

Answer (score 4):

In Ubuntu 16.04 this is how to open it in Terminal:

Go to the `File Manager > Edit > Preferences > Behavior` for `Executable Text Files` and select  `Ask each time`.

The problem is that it's by default set to `View Executable Files when they are opened`.

Answer (score 3):

If you place your shell script or other executable you create in /usr/local/bin it will be found and executed without having to provide a folder path in the command line or adding ./ to the name. For example I created the following simple 3 line bash script to display disk UUIDs:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "* UUIDs must match in /etc/fstab and /boot/grub/menu.lst"
sudo blkid
```

I called the file uuid and placed it in /usr/local/bin. All I need enter on the command line is:

```
uuid
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem I have found on a few distributions is they have hidden the preferences option in Nautilus, but to fix it in Ubuntu and other distributions using Gnome3 is the same (literally just done the Fedora version of this and posting the actual fix to remind me how in the future).

1. Install `dconf-editor`

   ```
   sudo apt-get install dconf-editor
   ```
2. Run `dconf-editor` using the user account you want this on, i.e NOT root

   ```
   dconf-editor
   ```
3. Navigate to the following schema:

   org.gnome.nautilus.preferences
4. Change the default option to not open by default:

   Find `executable-text-activation` click the word `display` and change to `ask`

that will give you the option to edit, view or run the file going forward

Answer (score 2):

Well, I too faced the same problem. I wanted to execute the .sh file and it opened with Gedit on CentOS 7. So here is what I did:

1. I navigated to the path of the `.sh` file I wanted to execute.
2. I opened the terminal.
3. And I simply dragged and dropped the on the terminal window and it automatically took that file along with the path as input.
4. Hit Enter and you are good to go!

Answer (score 2):

I am a noob in Linux and I just had the same problem. If all else fails:

1. Open terminal
2. Open the folder containing the .sh file
3. Drag and drop the file into the terminal window
4. The file's path appears in terminal. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
5. Voila, your .sh file is run.

Answer (score -3):

You can also use `.` tricks, with the suggestion of other answers.

For example:

`chmod +x filename.sh`, assuming you have already gone to the path to file then run the file with any one of these command:

```
sh filename.sh

./filename.sh

. filename.sh
```

Comment: _warning_: These three commands are _not_ equivalent. If your shebang references a different binary (like Stack), then the third command will try parsing arguments with Bash, which will fail.