# How to run a script?

Tags: command-line, scripts, vmware

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I run .sh files in Terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38661/how-do-i-run-sh-files-in-terminal)

I need to install a special patch for vmware.
To do this, I downloaded the file and it was the file "linux", a text editor, it looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

case "` uname-m `" in
     x86_64)
         "$ 0" _64 "$ @"
         ;;
     *)
         "$ 0" _32 "$ @"
         ;;
esac
```

But how do I run it?

Answer (score 19):

To run a shell script you first give it permissions:

```
chmod u+x nameofthescript
```

Then you run it. Assuming you're in the directory where the script is:

```
./nameofthescript
```

If it needs to run with root privileges:

```
sudo ./nameofthescript
```

Answer (score 5):

Use a terminal and enter `sh /path/to/script.sh`.

For example, `sh ~/Downloads/script.sh` if your script is in your downloads folder.

Answer (score 2):

The file you've downloaded is a script file writter un shell ( the first line are the interpreter).
So to launch it, you have to open a terminal, like root45 said, terminal can be gnome-terminal or xterm program. 
The go the directory where you're shell script is saved (command cd), than launch manually your script : sh yourscript.sh