# Wifi stopped working after resume or reboot Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, network-manager

I have a dell vostro laptop with Ubuntu 14.04 dual boot with windows (wifi is working with windows). The wifi stopped working after resume/reboot. Wifi is unable to detect any networks.

PFB the related info

```
ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 5c:f9:dd:4b:2f:ca  
          inet addr:192.168.20.175  Bcast:192.168.20.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::5ef9:ddff:fe4b:2fca/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:16 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:1962 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1962 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:204810 (204.8 KB)  TX bytes:204810 (204.8 KB)

sudo lshw -C network

  *-network               
       description: Network controller
       product: BCM43142 802.11b/g/n
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=bcma-pci-bridge latency=0
       resources: irq:16 memory:d0500000-d0507fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: AR8161 Gigabit Ethernet
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 10
       serial: 5c:f9:dd:4b:2f:ca
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=alx duplex=full ip=192.168.20.175 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:45 memory:d0400000-d043ffff ioport:2000(size=128)
```

I tried `sudo service network-manager restart` but it did not help

Also, I managed to get wifi up again once by doing

```
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source broadcom-sta-common broadcom-sta-source && sudo apt-get install b43-fwcutter firmware-b43-installer
```

I have referred the following links :

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2218043
[Network connection error after suspend Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/450688/network-connection-error-after-suspend-ubuntu-14-04)
[Wireless networking not working after resume in Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/452826/wireless-networking-not-working-after-resume-in-ubuntu-14-04)
http://www.techytalk.info/ubuntu-fix-network-stopped-working-after-resume-from-sleep/

[How to run a script?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/77929/how-to-run-a-script) 
[Can't connect to a specific WiFi network (Ubuntu 14.04)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/567799/cant-connect-to-a-specific-wifi-network-ubuntu-14-04) 
[Why doesn't System Monitor show activity over ethernet connections?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/409007/why-doesnt-system-monitor-show-activity-over-ethernet-connections) 
http://www.overclock.net/t/1518258/solved-wireless-suddenly-stopped-working-in-ubuntu-14-04/10

I have failed to find a solution. Please help I' new to Ubuntu.

Thanks!