# Why can't I execute any .sh scripts?

Tags: command-line, permissions, application-development, executable

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I run .sh files in Terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38661/how-do-i-run-sh-files-in-terminal)

When I try to run  a .sh script in Terminal it says I have no permissions to do that.
And when I try to run an executable nothing happens at all!

Comment: You can start by adding to the question the commands you are using to run it on a terminal, the output of `ls -l` while on the script's folder and any further steps you tried and what errors you get when trying to run the script. Add that information to the question instead of adding it as a comment.

Comment: chmod +x a.sh; ./a.sh (make it executeable first).

Comment: That's a hard guessing game. First, provide the output of `ls -l script.sh`, and a first line of your script.