# .sh script won't run

Tags: 12.04, server, scripts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I run .sh files in Terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38661/how-do-i-run-sh-files-in-terminal)

I'm trying to [install Craftbukkit](http://wiki.bukkit.org/Setting_up_a_remote_Linux_server) on my Ubuntu 12.04 server.  However, I'm having issues with step seven, which instructs me to run `./craftbukkit.sh`.

If I run it as a normal user, then I get a permissions error.  If I run it using sudo, then I get `sudo: ./craftbukkit.sh: command not found`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 23):

You need to chmod the file 1st before run.

```
chmod +x file.sh
```

Now your can run your .sh file as follows

```
./file.sh
```

Another way to run .sh file in Linux

```
sh file.sh
```

OR

```
bash file.sh
```

Comment: It was already executable.

Answer (score 4):

According to the wiki page of [bukkit](http://wiki.bukkit.org/Setting_up_a_remote_Linux_server).

> [...] **type `sh craftbukkit.sh`** to execute the script you wrote before. Your server
>   will start and keep running until you stop it (or until it crashes).

Comment: Thanks, this helped me find the issue (Java wasn't installed.  Duh....)

Comment: Passing an explicit shell instead of letting the system infer the right script form the shebang might lead to errors. It*s just a matter of luck that it worked here.

Comment: @userunknown: Well these are the contents of craftbukkit.sh:
`#!/bin/sh
screen java -Xms1024M -Xmx1024M -jar craftbukkit.jar` http://wiki.bukkit.org/Setting_up_a_remote_Linux_server

Comment: I told you, that it might be a matter of luck, if it works. Why don't you use `sudo ./craftbukkit.sh`?

Comment: @userunknown You have to `chmod +x ./craftbukkit.sh` first, in this situation..

Comment: @userunknown: Actually it must be run this way (as per the wiki page), check my improved answer.

Comment: @pl1nk: Do you think the people behind craftbukkit are the ultimate authority in shell scripting? One thing is to heal a lousy installation routine with sloppy advices by half educated programmers - get the thing running - the other thing is to learn something which isn't too localized. `chmod` is fine thing to do, if it isn't executable per se - else you have to remember always to put `sh` in front, and not `bash` and you can't use auto completition to run it and you won't find it with `find  -executable`, not with `whereis` and  `which` - a whole bunch of drawbacks.

Comment: @userunknown: Did you even checked this wiki page? I'm wondering to which `lousy installation routine` are you refering to ? I don't agree with your comment and especially with your characterization to the `half educated programmers` ? Seriously ?

Comment: @EliahKagan: `It was already executable.`, Author: SomeKittens, Jun 19 at 18:21 in a comment to penreturns answer.