# How to make a file (e.g. a .sh script) executable, so it can be run from a terminal

Tags: command-line, executable

I have a script.sh file and type of this file is shellscript file. I want to make this file as application/x-executable file. How can I make it?

Comment: related to [How do I run .sh files in Terminal?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/38661/how-do-i-run-sh-files-in-terminal/38666)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I run .sh files?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38661/how-do-i-run-sh-files)

Comment: It is not a duplicate, because I have asked specifically about making it application/x-executable. The other question just asks for opening sh file in terminal.

Answer (score 598, accepted):

You can mark the file as executable:

```
chmod +x filename.sh
```

You can then execute it like this:

```
./filename.sh
```

If you want to use a different command to start it, you can add an alias:

```
gedit ~/.bashrc
```

Add this at the end of the file:

```
alias <new name>='/home/<full path to script>/filename.sh'
```

Open a new terminal session or type `source ~/.bashrc` in your terminal to apply.
Then simply use the new name to start the script.

Comment: Do you know how to use sudo command after entering the command as:      "alias command1 = '/home/user_name/dir/script.sh'. In mine, it works without sudo, but not with it.

Comment: You need to restart bash after editing the .bashrc run: exec bash to restart bash.

Comment: Why does the executable file be `./filename.sh` and not just `filename.sh`?

Comment: @user1993 yes, I am also looking for a way to make it executable just by `filename` and not `./filename`

Comment: @user1993 Generally, using `./filename.sh` specifies a file in the current directory and using `filename.sh` specifies a file in the current directory or any directory of PATH.  The first usage removes any uncertainty as to which file is accessed.  In this case, you are attempting to execute the script with bash or another interpreter (by virtue of assumed `#!/bin/bash` as first line in your script) just by entering the filename.  This usage requires the directory is specified.  Alternatively, you can try `bash filename.sh` which seems to work with unspecified directory.

Answer (score 64):

There are two ways of making a file executable:

**GUI Method:**

Right-click the file and select Properties.
Go to the permissions tab, then tick the box `Execute: [ ] Allow executing file as program` or in Nautilus `Program: [ ] Allow this file to run as a program` in Thunar.

[image]

**Terminal / Command method:**

You can either use:

`cd /to/my/required/directory`

Then run

`chmod +x filename.extension`

Or just run:

`chmod +x /path/to/your/filename.extension`

`chmod` does also have some more advanced options:

The spaces are to show that it is split up: `- rwx --- ---`

The first set of `---` is User. The second is Group and the last is Other (anyone else)

r stands for Read, w for Write and x for eXecute.

So to allow everyone to read it, but only Group to execute and User to read and write it (but for some reason not execute) would be:

`-rw- rx- r--` But this would be added to the command as:

`chmod +rw-rx-r-- /path/to/file.extension`

`chmod` also can do this in numbers. It is based on binary (I think, as it is 1,2 and 4)

So there are these numbers:

Execute by user is `100`.
Execute by group is `010`.
Execute by other is `001`.

Write by user is `200`.
Write by group is `020`.
Write by other is `002`.

Read by user is `400`.
Read by group is `040`.
Read by other is `004`.

Then you add these together to get the desired combination.

So to allow everyone to read it, but only Group to execute and User to write it (but for some reason not execute) would be:

`400 + 040 + 004` and `010` and `200`

That adds up to 600 + 050 + 004 = 654.

You could then run the command.

`chmod +654 /path/to/file.extension` to set it.

And to set all permissions you can type:

`chmod +rwxrwxrwx /path/to/file.extension`

Or (this is a bit easier to write, but harder to remember each one):

`chmod +777 /path/to/file.extension`

Finally, you can do:

`chmod -777 /path/to/file.extension`

To take all permissions away from everyone.

And:

`chmod +300 /path/to/file.extension`

To add read and write for user, without affecting any other permissions (e.g. Execute permissions).

[This website](http://ss64.com/bash/chmod.html) has a very useful little grid checkbox thing, whereby you can tick the options you want and it gives you the command:

[image]

However, not all the possible combinations are sensible to use; the main ones that are used are the following:

755 - `Owner` has all, and `Group` and `Other` can read and execute

700 - `Owner` has all

644 - `Owner` can read and write, and `Group` and `Other` can read

600 - `Owner` can read and write

And, if you're using non-trivial user groups:

775 - `Owner` can read and write, and `Group` and `Other` can read

770 - `Owner` and `Group` have all, and `Other` can read and execute

750 - `Owner` has all, and `Group` can read and execute

664 - `Owner` and `Group` can read and write, and `Other` can just read

660 - `Owner` and `Group` can read and write

640 - `Owner` can read and write, and `Group` can read

777 and 666 are rarely used, except in /tmp.

Thanks [Ilmari Karonen](https://askubuntu.com/users/35897/ilmari-karonen) for [pointing out](https://askubuntu.com/questions/484718/how-to-make-a-file-executable/484719?noredirect=1#comment646215_484719) the ones in common usage!

Comment: Does't it is based on octal (8-base) instead of binary (2-based)? In binary you can have only 0 and 1, while in octal you can have 0, 1, ... 6, 7

Comment: @Justinas binary in that 7 = 4+2+1 -  111 represents Read and Write and Execute.

Comment: the ```chmod +101``` style permission modifications is what I was looking for.  Thanks for this.

Comment: An extremely thorough answer!

Answer (score 9):

Run:

```
chmod +x /path/to/file.sh
```

To make it un-executable, run:

```
chmod -x /path/to/file.sh
```

For example i created `.sh` file:

```
vi tester12.sh
```

After i write some code on vi editor, i'll exit from vi editor:

```
:wq!
chmod +x tester12.sh
./tester12.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

### Let all users run your script

As stated you can set the execution bit of the file to make it executable with `chmod +x`. But you can also use `chmod a+x`:

```bsh
$ ll file_command.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 rick rick 17 Sep 19 08:55 file_command.txt

$ chmod a+x file_command.txt

$ ll file_command.txt
-rwxrwxr-x 1 rick rick 17 Sep 19 08:55 file_command.txt*
```

**NOTES:**

- A script doesn't have to end with `.sh` it can end in `.txt` as shown here, or have no extension whatsoever.
- Instead of just `+x` (only you can execute the script), use `a+x` so all users can execute the script.
- The file name has a `*` appended to it to indicate it is executable. Also the file name changes color to green on most systems.

[image: make script executable]

---

### Run a script without making it executable

You can still run a bash script without making it executable. For example:

```bsh
$ echo "echo Hello World" > file_command.txt

$ cat file_command.txt
echo Hello World

$ bash file_command.txt
Hello World
```

**NOTES:**

- First we create a script containing `echo Hello World`.
- Then we confirm the script called `file_command.txt` is correct.
- Lastly we run the script by calling `bash` and passing it the script name. The `bash`command is actually store as `/bin/bash` and it is an executable on all Ubuntu systems.
- Creating a file of commands saves you from adding the **shebang** `#!/bin/bash` as the first line in a script.
- Creating a file of commands saves you from making it executable with `chmod +x` or `chmod a+x`.

Comment: What do you mean by a "file of commands"? When exactly do we need the shebang, and when do we not?