# How to make a file executable?

Tags: command-line, scripts, executable

How can I make my file so that I can double click on it, and it runs. It is a `.sh` script, but I also have files that say:

`executable (application/x-executable)`

in the description of what they are.

I can't run any of these from terminal, or by double clicking.

If possible, I would like a way using either the GUI or a Terminal, but not a combination of the two.

Here is a screenshot of what I see when I right click then go on properties. The file first:

[image: properties of executable file]

And the shell script here:

[image: properties of shell script]

NB: I accept that this is a duplicate (I was looking for it, and couldn't find it, so asked + answered it, hoping that I would find it) however, I don't think the question about .desktop files is a duplicate.

Comment: see the permissions tab in you screenshots.

Comment: We need more information. Could be anything from improper permissions to unmet dependencies to incorrect path to running a windows program on linux.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

There are two ways of making a file executable:

**GUI Method:**

Go to the permissions tab, then tick the box `Execute: [✓]` Allow executing file as program.

[image]

**Command line method:**

Just run:

```
chmod +x /path/to/your/file.txt
```

Note that `chmod` does also have some more advanced options. It accepts three groups of options, represented as `--- --- ---`. The first set of `---` is User. The second is Group and the last is Other (everyone else).

`r` stands for Read, `w` for Write and `x` for eXecute.

To allow everyone to read it, but only Group to execute and User to read and write it would be `-rw- rx- r--`. This would be added to the command as:

```
chmod +rw-rx-r-- /path/to/file.extension
```

`chmod` also can do this in numbers. It is based on binary.

So there are these numbers:

Execute by user is `100`.
Execute by group is `010`.
Execute by other is `001`

Write by user is `200`.
Write by group is `020`.
Write by other is `002`.

Read by user is `400`.
Read by group is `040`.
Read by other is `004`.

Then you add these together to get the desired combination.

So to allow everyone to read it, but only Group to execute and User to write it would be `400 + 040 + 004` and `010` and `200`

That adds up to `600 + 050 + 004 = 654`.

You could then run the command.

```
chmod +654 /path/to/file.extension
```

to set it. So to set all permissions you can run:

```
chmod +rwxrwxrwx /path/to/file.extension
```

or

```
chmod +777 /path/to/file.extension
```

Finally, you can do:

```
chmod -777 /path/to/file.extension
```

To take all permissions away from everyone.

And:

```
chmod +300 /path/to/file.extension
```

To add read and write for the user, without affecting any other permissions (e.g. Execute permissions).

[This website](http://ss64.com/bash/chmod.html) has a very useful little tool, whereby you can tick the options you want and it gives you the command:

[image]

However, not all the possible combinations are sensible to use; the main ones that are used are the following:

- 755 - `Owner` has all, and `Group` and `Other` can read and execute
- 700 - `Owner` has all
- 644 - `Owner` can read and write, and `Group` and `Other` can read
- 600 - `Owner` can read and write

And, if you're using non-trivial user groups:

- 775 - `Owner` can read and write, and `Group` and `Other` can read
- 770 - `Owner` and `Group` have all, and `Other` can read and execute
- 750 - `Owner` has all, and `Group` can read and execute
- 664 - `Owner` and `Group` can read and write, and `Other` can just read
- 660 - `Owner` and `Group` can read and write
- 640 - `Owner` can read and write, and `Group` can read

777 and 666 are rarely used, except in `/tmp`.

Thanks [Ilmari Karonen](https://askubuntu.com/users/35897/ilmari-karonen) for [pointing out](https://askubuntu.com/questions/484718/how-to-make-a-file-executable/484719?noredirect=1#comment646215_484719) the ones in common usage!

Comment: more info: `chmod --help`

Comment: You can also: `chmod +700 /path/to/your/filename.extension`

Comment: The community help wiki is at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/, and https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions would apply to this question, I suppose. Unlike Ask Ubuntu it's not a Q/A style resource.

Comment: You can also provide an answer as "community wiki", it is an option in the lower left corner of the "Answer" box. See http://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/community-wiki

Comment: Your screenshot shows a *very* bad example of file permissions. I can't think of any valid reason to *ever* make an executable file (or most other files, for that matter) writable by anyone, and plenty of reasons not to do that. Basically, the generally useful file permission sets (excluding advanced stuff like setuid/gid) are 755, 700, 644 and 600 (and, if you're using non-trivial user groups, 775, 770, 750, 664, 660 and 640). About the only things you should ever see with 777 or 666 permissions are `/tmp` (which is really 1777), device files and symlinks (whose permissions don't matter).

Comment: "To add read and write for the user ...." `chmod +300 /path/to/file.extension` wouldn't this line in the above answer add only exceute and write permissions to the user[100+200=300] ??