# Cannot install dpkg due to dependecies

Tags: dpkg, dependencies, deb

I am trying to install [ImFusion](https://www.imfusion.com/downloads/Demo/imfusionsuite-demo-2.15.1_ubuntu18.04_amd64.deb) in Ubuntu 19.10. It displays error that says dependencies are not installed. When I try to run `sudo apt -f install`, it says that it is removing the ImFusion package which was not installed. How can I install dependencies in such case.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The messages in the error messages you received are your first clue.

Comment: This isn't a dependencies problem but a different Ubuntu version one.

Answer (score 0):

I sincerely suggest you try with the AppImage variant because the unique DEB file available is for Ubuntu 18.04, but you have the 19.10.

Using the AppImage variant is a really easy task to do.

Simply download it from https://www.imfusion.com/downloads/Demo/imfusionsuite-demo-2.15.1.AppImage, change the file permission adding the Executable rights (click with the right button of the mouse, properties/permissions - [take a look here](https://askubuntu.com/a/484719/1060836)) and after running it with a simple double-click.

And that's all! :)