# TOR Related Question

Tags: tor

So I dont want to install the TOR Browser Bundle on my computer, I just want to execute (open) it from the .sh file that is provided when you download the TBB from the tor site. But for some odd reason when I click open the .sh file will not open. ALL other shell scripts that I have executed have opened successfully, all but this TOR one. Can some plz tell me what I can do. I know you can install it via PPA, but like I mentioned I dont want to install it. I have already set all .sh files to "run executable text files when they are opened" in my nautilus preferences.  I just upgraded to 14.04 a few nights ago. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `I have already set all .sh files to "run executable text files when they are opened" in my nautilus preferences` <-- Worst plan ever

Comment: It's my understanding that shell scripts not initializing some things when they are double-click run is something that happens with 14.04 *and it's probably a good thing*.  Instead of setting it to double-click open, you can just make a .desktop file that runs it via bash, so it's accessible that way instead.

Comment: How do I do that  hbdgaf?

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure the box is checked after the upgrade, and then make the script executable: [How to make a file (e.g. a .sh script) executable, so it can be run from terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/229589/how-to-make-a-file-e-g-a-sh-script-executable-so-it-can-be-ran-from-termina)

Then you can double click it and it will run.