# What am I doing wrong with the shell script? Noob

Tags: command-line, scripts, gedit

I created a new document, opened it with gedit and the script is very simple and it works in terminal, basically something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
sudo blah blah blah
```

But when I save it on the document, put on the execution tick in the properties and double click the file then gedit simply opens it again so what is there I should do to make the file work as a shell script to launch the command, I searched, but nothing answers my question because everywhere it says (or so I believe) that having the first line #!/bin/sh turns the document into a shell script.

Comment: There is *one more* step you need to make it runnable, see [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/286621/how-do-i-run-executable-scripts-in-nautilus). You might also need to [mark your script as executable](http://askubuntu.com/a/485001/44179) before it will run.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a desktop file, eg. **name.desktop** which contains the following structure:

> ```
> [Desktop Entry]
> Type=Application
> Name=your script name
> Exec=/path/to/your/script.sh  
> Terminal=true     <-if you need sudo (to type your password)
> ```

Make both this file and your script executable (e.g. chmod 700 script.sh). Now you can double click your desktop file to launch your script.