# Apache virtual hosts not working (error 403)

Tags: apache2, virtualhost

I have installed apache2, php and mysql server to my ubuntu 14.04 and was tested and everything is working as expected.

I have application created using codeigniter & was past developed on mac osx, so I create the following in order to run it on my ubuntu:

create new site configuration file inside sites-available named payroll-v1.conf like below:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName  payroll.v1
DocumentRoot /home/ahmed-saber/workspace/payroll-v1/

<Directory /home/ahmed-saber/workspace/payroll-v1/>
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
Require all granted
</Directory> 

</VirtualHost>
```

adding the line below to etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1   payroll.v1
```

although my application not working and always output 403 forbidden even if i trying to access any static html page for test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [403 error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) means that your pages are inaccessible for Apache.

Setting `chmod -R 755` as you did, made it accessible for everybody on your system - every user, program, [daemon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daemon_%28computing%29) etc. Furthermore, you have made all files executable this way (see [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions) or [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/229589/how-to-make-a-file-e-g-a-sh-script-executable-so-it-can-be-ran-from-termina) for mor info on permissions and executables on Linux).

---

More secure, yet simple solution, will be adding yourself to Apache's group (in Ubuntu its `www-data`) and then changing your Apache workspace to this group:

```
sudo adduser ahmed-saber www-data
sudo chown .www-data /home/ahmed-saber/workspace/
chmod 750 /home/ahmed-saber/workspace/
```

For more secure approach you could use [Access Control List](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissionsACLs), which might be a little more complicated.

In situations like this, you can always check Apache's error log (`/var/log/apache2/error.log`). If you are developing web pages you can keep one terminal window opened with "live view" of logs (`error.log` or `access.log` or whatever), like this:

```
tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a line

```
ServerName  payroll.v1
```

inside your `VirtualHost` definition to tell Apache the hostname used for this VirtualHost.

Comment: the line already there, I miss to write it here and I edited the question, but nothing going to be work

Answer (score 0):

The issue solved by running the following

> sudo chmod -R 755 /home/ahmed-saber/workspace/*

also blank page due to some php errors