# Hiding terminal when executing zenity bash script by double click

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, zenity

Is there a way to hide terminal when a bash script for zenity is executed

eg:

```
szAnswer=$(zenity --entry --text "where are you?" --entry-text "at home"); echo $szAnswer
```

I want to hide the terminal and only gui-zenity should be visible while executing by double click

Comment: How is this script executed when double-clicking? Or on what do you click?

Comment: I have saved the script as `zen.sh` its executing without any problem.  The problem is when executing the script (double click) terminal also runs with the GUI.  I want to prevent this, i want only GUI to run

Comment: Does the first line of the script say `#!/bin/bash`? If not, add it.

Comment: @the_Seppi yes i have added `#!/bin/bash`

Answer (score 5):

To launch a script without the terminal visible, use a `.desktop` file.

1. Create a file `zen.desktop`
2. Put in the contents of the file using gedit or you favorite text editor(terminal=false will make sure it doesn't show the terminal, although this option should default):

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]
   Type=Application
   Terminal=false
   Name=zenity-app
   Exec=/home/user/zen.sh
   ```

   Replace Exec with where your script is located.
3. Make sure to set the permission to execute on the `.desktop` file (and your script) - [How to make a file (e.g. a .sh script) executable, so it can be run from terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/229589/how-to-make-a-file-e-g-a-sh-script-executable-so-it-can-be-ran-from-termina)
4. Double click the desktop file and see if it works.

Comment: Great stuff. Here's the link to the file-format spec. for `.desktop` files: https://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/