# How to get Teamspeak 3 for Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, teamspeak

I have looked around and cannot find any solutions to my problem. I have downloaded ts3 using this video for 12.04.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WbBBPo3A-jE
The problem I'm getting is that when I double click on the file at the end of the file as shown at the end of the video it just comes up in Gedit. I am not sure what to do and have browsed around. As well s that, I am not really sure about what I am doing with the system I am using and the Terminal. Everything I have searched I either do not understand and doesn't work when I try it (Maybe because I am doing it incorrectly) or isn't for my version and isn't valid for me. I would like to know how to run it from the stage I have got up to. I understand that the version I am using is out of date but I am unable to update it at the current moment.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Support for Ubuntu 13.04 officially ended on 27 January 2014. You can upgrade to a newer and supported version following [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release).

Comment: please consider doing an upgrade to a newer version as suggested @M.Becerra

Comment: I am unable to update it at this current moment in time and do not know when I will be able to.

Answer (score 1):

## Make the file executable

Before double clicking on the file do the following:

1. Right click on the file
2. Select **Properties**
3. Select **Permissions** tab
4. Check the box **Allow executing file as program**
5. Close the properties window

## Change how Nautilus behaves when you click on an executable text file

6. Go to the `Edit > Preferences` menu in **Nautilus**
7. Go to the **Behavior** tab of the `Files Preference` window.
8. Click either **Run executable text file when opened** or **Ask each time** and close the window.

[image]

Now double clicking will run the file as program or it will open a window and you will be able to choose whether to edit the file in Gedit or run it.

Also see [How to make a file (e.g. a .sh script) executable, so it can be run from terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/229589/how-to-make-a-file-e-g-a-sh-script-executable-so-it-can-be-run-from-termina)

Hope this helps

Comment: I have already made the file executable and it still starts up Gedit when I run it