# Why doesn't the keyboard screenshot button work on Ubuntu with GNOME shell?

Tags: shortcut-keys, gnome-shell, screenshot, gnome-screenshot, print-screen

It works on Ubuntu 17.04 with Unity, however neither via upgrade or a fresh install, does the screenshot keyboard button work on Ubuntu 17.10 with GNOME shell.

Can anyone tell me why or how to fix it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The <kbd>PrtScr</kbd>/<kbd>Print</kbd> key still works – but now (U17.10) has different actions bound to it. Go to

*Settings* → *Devices* → *Keyboard*

and scroll down to *Screenshots*. It shows

[image]

If that's sufficient for you and you can remember these keystrokes, then you are done. Else refer to [@pomsky](https://askubuntu.com/users/480481/pomsky)'s [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1013743/504066) and set up a shortcut to launch `gnome-screenshot --interactive` instead.

Comment: What is the button called <kbd>Print<\kbd>

Comment: @Viesturs I don't get that question. It is the button that is either labelled `Print or `PrintScreen` or `PrtScr` or something like that. Sometimes they are labelled in your current language, like `Druck` on a German keyboard.

Comment: Try changing the shortcuts [twice](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/firefox/+bug/1855298). The first time they did not register for me.

Answer (score 5):

Now once you press <kbd>PrintScreen</kbd>, `gnome-screenshot` captures a screenshot and saves it in `~/Pictures/` without asking the user.

You may set a custom keyboard shortcut to launch `gnome-screenshot` in interactive mode, i.e. when the following window appears providing the user some choices:

[image]

and the options to save or discard the screenshot, chose location to save etc. after capturing.

To set the custom shortcut follow the steps from [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/975341/480481).