# Is there a screen recorder for GNOME with Wayland?

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell, wayland, screencast, desktop-recording

I am using Ubuntu 18.04.01 LTS. I have spent a lot of time searching for Screen Recorders for the Ubuntu GNOME Wayland.

I have tried several Screen Recorders such as **Simple Screen Recorder** and **Vokoscreen**, but the result is only a blank screen with the cursor.

Any suggestions for me?

Comment: Maybe `Shift-Ctrl-Alt-R` is sufficient? See https://askubuntu.com/a/1013746/504066 (Loosely related question, but shows the shortcuts)

Comment: Yes, but I think it's only good for record short screencast. And for me, I need longer duration or duration that I can customize when I record tutorial video. It should be good if there is a way to change its default duration.

Comment: It was just an idea. I was surprised to see that a very simple recorder already ships with Ubuntu. Never mind.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Green Recorder](https://github.com/foss-project/green-recorder) claims to support Wayland.

> ### How it works?
>
> It uses the D-Bus API to connect to the built-in screencasting tool in
> GNOME Shell. It uses this to record video. To record audio, it
> launches an instance of ffmpeg in the background. After the recording
> is finished, it merges the two files into the WebM file.
>
> For Xorg, it uses ffmpeg only for both audio and video.
>
> By default, On Wayland only, Green Recorder uses the V8 encoder
> instead of the default V9 encoder in GNOME Shell because of the CPU &
> RAM consumption issue with V9. Which - now - should also give you
> better performance. On Xorg, each format uses its own default encoder.

You can install from ["FOSS Project" teams's PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Efossproject/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) by running the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fossproject/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install green-recorder
```

Comment: Thanks. I've tried to install Green Recorder and it worked. But till now it only supports webm format as you said too. Maybe I can convert the  webm to mp4. Over all it just works and I think it's the only one solution to record screen in Wayland session.

Comment: Project is discontinued :/

Comment: Please edit to specify this solution does not work anymore. The package has been removed.

Answer (score 7):

Gnome has builtin screen recorder:
https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/ScreenCasting#Using_Gnome.27s_embedded_screencast_tool

Pressing Alt+Ctrl+Shift+R will start recording.

Comment: no audio in my recording

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Ubuntu 21.04 and Wayland.

Comment: this is hacky but to get audio I manually run audacity and this at the same time, and then at the end I run `ffmpeg -i audacity_audio.wav -i screen_record.webm out.mp4`. i'd like not to do that of course but it works

Answer (score 4):

sorry it might be a bit late, but you can increase the duration of the built-in one by running this command in terminal:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys max-screencast-length 600
```

Replace 600 with the number of seconds you want to be able to record for.

I've been intrigued with this for a while and have found the way to disable Wayland!
Run this command:

```
sudo nano /etc/gdm3/daemon.conf
```

and find #WayLandEnabled=false

Remove the #. Then
Ctrl + X, then click y, then enter.
Restart your computer.
Done! You are now using DirectX again. All your screen recorders should now work. The built-in screen recorder (Ctrl+Alt+Shift+R) should be a LOT smoother now as well for old laptops.

Answer (score 4):

I couldn’t find a good screen recorder for Wayland. So I made one 
https://github.com/HasinduLanka/screencorder

It’s stable and working well on Wayland.

If you know HTML/JS well, you can contribute to make frontend better

## How this screen recorder works on wayland?

Most screen recorders out there do not work on wayland. Why?

Because wayland is much secure than old X11. Wayland doesn't let every program to see what others doing. It's a bit harder to gain access.
But web browsers, like Chromium have handled these security features properly. That's why we use a local Progressive Web App as the frontend and a backend written in Go. The PWA records the screen and sends them to the backend as blobs. Backend records system sounds and combines all together in realtime.