# Screencast only records a black box

Tags: 19.04, screencast, kazam, obs-studio

Using [Kazam](https://launchpad.net/kazam) or [OBS](https://github.com/obsproject/obs-studio/wiki/Install-Instructions) to record my screen always results in a blank screen.  Google searches do not show results for 19.04, only past versions.  Any help?

Comment: If using Wayland instead of X, most screen recorders currently don't work (applications lack permission to see pixels outside their window). See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1097784 for a list of those that do work with Wayland.

Comment: What happens when you install Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS, install and test Kazam and OBS, alongside your 19.04 install? Kazam development is inactive so stabler releases may work where bleeding edge interim releases fail.  Please click [edit] and report the results. Please don't click on Add Comment; use [edit] instead.

Comment: Are you using Wayland? Please run the following command and add the output to your question: `echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After looking through some comments, I have found that you need to have XORG video server enabled.

You can check that by running `echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE`.

If it says Wayland, then you can take these steps:

1. Save your files and log out of your account.
2. Go to log in normally, but do not click **sign in**.  Instead, click the gear beside the sign in button.
3. Select either **Ubuntu** if you also see **Ubuntu on Wayland** as an option, or **Ubuntu on XORG**.

And you can now use your screencast app.

(Thanks to user535733, pomsky, and K7AAY for providing help!)

Comment: anyone knows why this is working ?