# Problem running OBS in ubuntu studio 19.10

Tags: graphics, 19.10, obs-studio

when I try to start I get the error message: Failed to initialize video.  Your GPU may not be supported, or your graphics drivers may need to be updated.

I've searched alot about the problem but the only thing I can find is that it might be a problem with opengl. Maybe I got a old version.
I've installed ubuntu studio 19.10 on two laptops and I got the same problem on both.

where do I start, what should I look for?

regards
Henke

Comment: Just so you know, Ubuntu 19.10 will soon be unsupported (9 months lifetime). So no fixes, driver or software updates.

Comment: are you using wayland or x11. wayland does not support most of screen recording or screencasting apps. However green recorder claims to support wayland https://github.com/mhsabbagh/green-recorder     https://askubuntu.com/questions/1097784/is-there-a-screen-recorder-for-gnome-with-wayland

Answer (score 0):

1. Open your prefered text editor
2. Write in there **LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=1 obs**
3. Save the file on desktop with name **run_obs_studio.sh**
4. Right click on file, Click **Properties**, go to **Permissions** tab and make it executable.
5. Launch the file and you are done.

This work around fixed the same issue happened with my installation.