# Configure OBS Screen Recorder for GNOME Dsktop

Tags: gnome, wayland, desktop-recording, obs-studio, video-recording

I am trying to record some footage of my gameplay with obs studio running on Ubuntu 22.04.  The problem is, unless I do fullscreen, the recording device does not pick up the selected window.  The cause for this is that I am using a wayland window system, which does not seem to give permission for things to record it? Now this question has been asked before in a similar form [Is there a screen recorder for GNOME with Wayland?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1097784/is-there-a-screen-recorder-for-gnome-with-wayland) but no working resolution that will fit my case has been found.  I am wondering, is there a adapter somewhere that will work for 22.04? Or a way to allow this to work?

Comment: switch to xorg? apparently you can try setting `QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland` in your terminal before running `obs`, and it should allow you to select Pipewire (record one window) as a source. from [this it's foss article](https://itsfoss.com/screen-record-obs-wayland/)

Comment: i still get the black screen videos when i select any window other than fullscreen