# Ubuntu 18.04: Shift+PrintScreen doesn't offer a "save" window after a recent update

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell, screenshot, gnome-screenshot

I had an Ubuntu update, and my "screenshot" option is not the same as it used to be.
I used to press <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>PRINT SCREEN</kbd>, and then a menu asking me where I want to save my images appeared (the specific menu that used to appear is shown in the image below)

[image: Shift+prt sc]

Now this menu does not appear. <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>PRINT SCREEN</kbd> still works, but the above menu asking where I want to save my screenshot does not appear.

How do I get this functionality back?

By the way - I know that I can use "screenshot" from my command line, or that I can start that "screenshot" plugin, but I specifically liked this amazing sequence: PRT SCRN, then that specific menu asking where I want to save it pops up....

Here is the Ubuntu info after update:
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic

Comment: `apt-get changelog gnome-screenshot` doesn't show any recent changes. The latest entry is from 12 Oct 2017 which refers to [gnome-screenshot Actions don't work in default Ubuntu 17.10 session](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1720262). So I don't understand what could have happened to gnome-screenshot in Bionic.

Comment: ctrl+print will copy the image to clipboard... I can't figure out a way to get the dialog back though...

Comment: @DKBose It's not an issue with `gnome-screenshot` per se, the thing is screenshots with keyboard shortcuts e.g. <PrintScreen> are handled by GNOME shell itself (`gnome-settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys`). By default <Shift>+<PrintScreesn> is set to "save a screenshot of an area to Pictures". OP probably switched from Unity, that's why they're missing the "save prompt" feature.

Answer (score 7):

It seems they changed the way screenshots are managed, you can check the shortcuts in **Settings -> Device -> Keyboard -> Keyboard Shortcuts -> Screenshots**.

[image]

To have the screenshot menu back you can create a new custom shortcut (again from **Keyboard Shortcuts**) and put as command the following line:

```
gnome-screenshot -i
```

Comment: This is a good workaround, but it doesn't completely provide what OP is looking for. This keyboard shortcut is same as launching the GUI Screenshot application (app window with options: whole screen/current window/area -> capture the screenshot -> "save as" dialogue), whereas OP wants "*this amazing sequence: PRT SCRN, then that specific menu asking where I want to save it pops up*".

Comment: Oh yes, I've just found [your question and answer for ubuntu 17.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/975339/how-do-i-make-my-screenshot-ask-me-what-to-do-next-every-time). Why don't you try to open an issue on the [github repository](https://github.com/GNOME/gnome-screenshot)?

Answer (score 0):

Open keyboard -> keyboard shortcuts , at "search", input "print", and you can see some different actions for "snapshot save to pictures" and "copy snapshot to clipboard"

Just change this shortcut.

[image]