# How do I run a command at start up on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS?

Tags: 18.04, autostart, startup-applications

I need to start a command on startup. I want to run this command:

```
xgamma -gamma 0.70
```

I have used Startup Applications but it doesn't work. I have put the command in the Startup Applications:

[image: Startup application]

Comment: yes sorry i have put the same command in the start up i will take another screenshot of how it looks thanks  and what is this command do echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE. –

Comment: It tells us if you are running X or Wayland. See `man echo`.

Comment: x11. – it give me this what is the different can you tell me please i'm new ubuntu user

Comment: Comments are not intended for conversation, but to help you improve your question. AskUbuntu's format is Question/Answer, not discussion. If you wish to discuss side issues ("say, what does this mean?"), then consider opening a thread at our sibling site http://ubuntuforums.org, which IS converstional, and does have threads that wander.

Comment: ok can you please help me on just run this command on startup thanks

Answer (score 3):

Thanks, pomsky
I have found a way to make it after doing 
these steps

1. Create a new text file, say `set-xgamma.sh` somewhere
2. add the following lines to the file:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   sleep 7 
   xgamma -gamma 0.70
   ```

   and save the file.
3. Make the script executable.
4. use this command `crontab -e`
5. put `@reboot sh $HOME/set-gamma.sh &` there with your file path
6. save it by clicking <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> then <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> to exit and it works :)

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a shell script for the command. Create a new text file, say `set-xgamma.sh` somewhere and add the following lines to the file:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   xgamma -gamma 0.70
   ```

   and save the file.
2. Make the script executable (refer to [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/485001/480481)).
3. In Startup Applications, while editing the program, click <kbd>Browse...</kbd> next to the '*Command*' textbox and select the `set-xgamma.sh` file you just created.