# Automate a command line when I power on my computer?

Tags: 18.04, automation

With Ubuntu 18.04, I need the command line `xrandr --output DP-1 --scale 0.5x0.5`. How can I automate that command when I power on my computer?

**EDIT**

I created the `/etc/rc.local` file, and in that file I have written

```
#!/bin/bash

xrandr --output DP-1 --scale 0.5x0.5

exit 0
```

The problem is if I restart the computer, the screen is identical and wrong. It seems to work if I run the command `bash /etc/rc.local`, but not if I restart the computer. How can I fix that?

Comment: Did you try to run your script via crontab?  See for instance [Getting a script to run on boot, not on login.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9806/getting-a-script-to-run-on-boot-not-on-login)

Comment: I don't want a cronjob. I just want to run a script automatically when I start up the computer

Comment: Question has been changed after an answer has been given. Should be reverted to the original question. One can always ask a new question.

Comment: @vanadium the edit didn't change the main question at all. Did you read somewhere that it's not ok to change question or just made it up?

Comment: @int_ua That is indeed the house rules. You can change a question to improve clarity. This site would however become hectic if everybody started to fundamentally change and add to the question all the time, making already posted answers to a previous version obsolete. This site has a specific format: it is not a support forum. It aims to be a knowledge base. If OP has new questions specifically to xrandr started from /etc/rc.local, then that is a different question here.

Comment: @vanadium you suggested rc.local yourself it was a clarification after your incorrect answer. And now you make up "rules" to cover up? Let's just close it as duplicate as correctly determined by Jacob

Comment: @int_ua indeed, I support this. I did not consider the specific command, only indicated how one can autoexecute a command during startup, and that might have been wrong.

Comment: @vanadium Thank you, deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`xrandr` will not work from `rc.local` because it needs Xorg (graphical mode) running. You need to use a way to autostart commands/applications for your Desktop Environment after you logged in as some user. AFAIU For default Ubuntu 18.04 [this method](https://askubuntu.com/a/1103773/20275) should work.

If you want the changes to affect Display Manager (the thing you see before logging in as a user) too that's more difficult, please add what DM you are using either by edit or comment.