# Open Firefox developer edition with ALT+F2

Tags: firefox, gnome-shell, alias

I recently installed Firefox developer edition following [this tutorial](https://gist.github.com/mahammad/e54e4be8938edf4d6c15) and I want to start Firefox by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and writing `firefox` in there. In terminal I added an alias,

```
firefox=/opt/firefox/firefox
```

and it works but it doesn't work from <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bash aliases do not work from the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> prompt as aliases are not expanded when the shell is not interactive (as per `man bash`).

If you want to run `/opt/firefox/firefox` by typing `firefox` in the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> prompt then follow the steps below.

1. Create a folder named `bin` in your home directory. Make sure `~/bin/` is in your PATH. If not, [add it](https://askubuntu.com/q/60218/480481).
2. Create a text file named `firefox` in the the aforementioned crated folder (i.e. in `~/bin/`).
3. Add the following lines to the `firefox` file

   ```bash
   #!/bin/bash
   /opt/firefox/firefox
   ```
4. Save the `firefox` file and [make it executable](https://askubuntu.com/q/229589/480481).

*Note:* now you can remove the alias you created if you wish as it would be redundant after following the steps above.

Comment: Hello, I did all the steps mentioned by you above, but my problem still persists..

Comment: sadly, I haven't rebooted, but I will right now, I will  comment the response! ```4.15.0-45-generic #48-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jan 29 16:28:13 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux``` this is my ```unaname -a``` output, for the version and flavour, UBUNTU 18.04 LTS,  and this is my ```echo $PATH``` output: ```/opt/firefox/firefox:/home/darenian/.local/share/umake/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin```

Comment: Came back with an answer, and yeah! It definetely works, thank you so much, can I ask you one more thing? such that can I edit the question and repond how can I make possible one more thing?

Comment: @C.Cristi Please remove the newly added part from the question as otherwise it may get closed as "too broad" (questions should be limited to a specific problem with enough detail here). Post a new question for the other issue if needed, but refer to this first: https://askubuntu.com/q/975178/480481 I believe this should be enough to solve your other problem.

Comment: done! and than you so much for the linked post!