# How To Start A Program With Its Name

Tags: filesystem, installed-programs

I've installed Matlab on my Ubuntu 18.04. Every time I want to open it I need to call it.

```
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2017a/bin/matlab
```

I think it is too long and waste of a little time. There has to be an easier way to open it. How can I open it simply by writing its name or is there any easier way?

Comment: You can add it to "path", or create an alias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your `~/.bashrc` file

```
export PATH=/usr/local/MATLAB/R2017a/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: It didn't work at first, but a little research on the net solved it. It should be without "matlab" at the end. Like this:

export PATH=/usr/local/MATLAB/R2017a/bin:$PATH

Answer (score 2):

You can either add `/usr/local/MATLAB/R2017a/bin/` [to your PATH](https://askubuntu.com/q/60218/480481) or create another script in a proper directory of executables in your home.

To do the second one follow the steps below.

1. Create a folder named `bin` in your home directory. (*Note:* This assumes the directory `~/bin/` is included in your PATH. If it isn't, you need to [add it to your path](https://askubuntu.com/q/60218/480481) first.)
2. Create a text file named `matlab` (the command you want to use) in the the aforementioned crated folder (i.e. in `~/bin/`).
3. Add the following lines to the `matlab` file

   ```bash
   #!/bin/bash
   /usr/local/MATLAB/R2017a/bin/matlab
   ```
4. Save the `matlab` file and [make it executable](https://askubuntu.com/q/229589/480481).