# Is it possible to find Snaps, FlatPaks and AppImages without installing any application into Ubuntu system?

Tags: software-installation, software-center, snap, flatpak, appimage

Sometimes a user may not want to install GUIs for Snap, FlatPak or AppImage, but wants to simply find applications by name or description and decide which version to install and from which software channel.

Is it possible to find Snaps, FlatPaks and AppImages without installing any application into Ubuntu system?

Comment: Well snap is preinstalled in Ubuntu and integrated into gnome-software, so by searching there you already search snaps. By installing flatpak (cli) and enabling flathub, it will integrate there as well, so searching will search apt, snap as well as flatpak versions of packages. AppImage I dunno.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Linux App Store development is stopped](https://github.com/linuxappstore/linuxappstore), this other project has the same aim: [AppOutlet](https://app-outlet.github.io/)

And it simply does the job.

To install AppOutlet:

- download the AppImage file from their [website](https://app-outlet.github.io/)
- [make the file executable](https://askubuntu.com/questions/229589/how-to-make-a-file-e-g-a-sh-script-executable-so-it-can-be-run-from-a-termi)

[image: App Outlet]

Comment: Thanks for update. Please write your answer in more reproducible way, describe steps how to use AppOutlet.

Answer (score 4):

**Update 20200517: the Linux App Store development is stopped.**

<s>Yes, it is possible with new open-source web-application named (guess how) *Linux App Store*.</s>

It is located on https://linuxappstore.io/ and allows to list all applications packed as Snap, FlatPak or AppImage and has search by name. Below is example for VLC:

> [image: search for VLC]

and we can see it is available from all three sources.

The project is in active development, anyone can improve it by [filing issue](https://github.com/linuxappstore/linuxappstore-frontend/issues).

<sub>I am not affiliated with this project in any way, I just wanted to share a good tool.</sub>