# How do I open an app in a certain workspace from terminal?

Tags: command-line, shortcut-keys, gnome-shell, workspaces

I use Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic Beaver with the GNOME Desktop environment. I would like to use keyboard shortcuts to open a webpage in a certain Chrome person in another workspace. Opening the webpage is no problem, but I don't know how to extend the command to open it in my second workspace. I have shortcuts to move it to an other workspace after it opens, but I would like to do it all at one (maybe calling a `.sh` file might help?). This is what I have so far:

```
google-chrome https://askubuntu.com/ --profile-directory="Person 0"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a hacky workaround, but I think this would achieve what you're looking for. You need to install `wmctrl` first by running the following command

```
sudo apt install wmctrl
```

Then you need to create a bash script. First create a text file and add the following lines to it.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
wmctrl -s 1
google-chrome --new-window https://askubuntu.com/ --profile-directory="Person 0"
```

(note that you need to use `wmctrl -s %n` in the second line if you want to open Chrome in the `%n+1`-th workspace). Save the file as, say `chrome-workspace2.sh`, and [make it executable](https://askubuntu.com/q/229589/480481).

Finally, while creating the keyboard shortcut, use the full path to this script as the command for the shortcut.