# How can I set xpad to open on two virtual workspaces at start up?

Tags: gnome, 22.04, thinkpad

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04 on a Thinkpad x1 carbon 7th gen.
I'm using the Gnome Desktop environment.

I'd like to configure the system such that on start-up 4 xpad pads are opened. 2 on the first desktop and 2 on the second desktop.

I have this working for the first two.

Unfortunately, the other two pads open over the first two on the first desktop (Ubuntu virtual workspaces).

How can I fix this?

Thank you

Comment: Do you mean Ubuntu's virtual `Workspaces` when you say desktops? If so I think you can do it using scripts and `wmctrl` as per this answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1187590/how-do-i-open-an-app-in-a-certain-workspace-from-terminal

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant. I'm not familiar with the exact terminology.

Comment: @codlord Thank you for your comment. I got it working, however not for xpad. I have two chromium windows opening on separate virtual workspaces on boot (which is great!) but I can not seem to do this with xpad.