# How can I open a game installer in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, games

I’m new in Ubuntu and I need help to install a game from https://download.grandlineadventures.com/glaclient-build1582.zip. The zip contains a linux file `glaclient-linux` but this doesn’t open.
How could I open it?

Comment: https://download.grandlineadventures.com/glaclient-build1582.zip this is the game that i try to install

Comment: contains a file named "glaclient-linux" but i can´t open it

Comment: What are you doing to 'open it' ?

Answer (score 1):

I’ve tried to download the archive and unzip the file `glaclient-linux`.
The command `file glaclient-linux` returns:

> glaclient-linux: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (GNU/Linux), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/l, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, BuildID[sha1]=79f804d0bc700ea0ff8e33462941eec21449ac41, stripped

It means this is a native binary executable file for x86-64 (aka amd64, 64-bit Intel), so it can be run directly on such a machine (not an old 32-bit Intel or Raspberry Pi, for example). You might have to [set the executable flag](https://askubuntu.com/questions/229589/how-to-make-a-file-e-g-a-sh-script-executable-so-it-can-be-run-from-a-termi) which is not preserved in ZIP files. To set the flag, issue the command

```
chmod +x glaclient-linux
```

in the folder where you have extracted the file (or provide its path).

Comment: I have no idea how to do it im coming from windows

i need to open the therminal and insert the comands chmod +x glaclient-linux?
i extracted it on the desk

Comment: Yes, or use the GUI method available in [another answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/485001/250300) to the question I linked.

Comment: i will try that

Comment: @MiguelAlvarado Have you been satisfied with my answer? If I could solve your problem, it would be nice if you [accepted](https://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer) my answer (✓). In the opposite case, please clarify your needs using [editing](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1209932/edit) or comments. See also [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers), [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/217657)