# How to unrar a .rar file if I cannot install unrar?

Tags: archive, extract, rar

How do I unrar a file if I cannot install unrar ? Below is the error message I got.

```
sudo apt install unrar-free
is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.
```

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it seems you are either using a public PC (in a cyber cafe, or a computer lab) where you do not have the root / sudo password, or there are restrictions.

You can try extracting it online (NOTE: To be on the safer side make sure your rar file doesn't contain any sensitive information.).

For example, you can use this site: http://online.b1.org/online

or

You can try using a portable app (for example an Appimage of an archiving software like 7zip or [Peazip](https://www.peazip.org/peazip-portable.html)) on your pendrive. These softwares don't need any installation, just download the appimage file, right click on the file and allow executing as a program (or use chmod command to make it executable if it is not) as described here: [How to make a file (e.g. a .sh script) executable, so it can be run from a terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/229589/how-to-make-a-file-e-g-a-sh-script-executable-so-it-can-be-run-from-a-termi)
(If it is not an appimage, follow the instructions given on the release page of the file.)
...and take it to whichever PC you need it, plug the pendrive, and run the portable program! That's all.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use [PeaZip](https://sourceforge.net/projects/peazip/) program which is quite portable and you can use it natively in linux without the need of a sudoer user.
It supports multiple archive types including RAR. Since it's on your system , you don't have to worry about the disclosure of your information ( as it's maybe the case in online extractors)