# Permission denied when using the terminal to install a program located in the download folder

Tags: software-installation

```
roberto@roberto-870-224:~$ cd ~/Downloads
roberto@roberto-870-224:~/Downloads$ ./daedalus-2.2.0-mainnet-14276.bin
bash: ./daedalus-2.2.0-mainnet-14276.bin: Permission denied
roberto@roberto-870-224:~/Downloads$
```

Comment: Let's start with the most common reason: Did you remember to make the file executable?

Comment: hi,how do i make it executable?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a file (e.g. a .sh script) executable, so it can be run from a terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/229589/how-to-make-a-file-e-g-a-sh-script-executable-so-it-can-be-run-from-a-termi)

Answer (score 1):

Change the permissions to executable...

```
chmod +x ./daedalus-2.2.0-mainnet-14276.bin
```

Comment: ok,  this is what i get:   roberto@roberto-870-224:~/Downloads$ chmod +x ./daedalus-2.2.0-mainnet-14276.bin
roberto@roberto-870-224:~/Downloads$

Comment: roberto@roberto-870-224:~/Downloads$ chmod +x ./daedalus-2.2.0-mainnet-14276.bin
roberto@roberto-870-224:~/Downloads$ ./daedalus-2.2.0-mainnet-14276.bin
../run: 1: ./nix/store/slls7lvg8yfdv9ax8mfw653sxfq49shv-startup: not found
roberto@roberto-870-224:~/Downloads$

Comment: roberto@roberto-870-224:~/Downloads$ ./daedalus-2.2.0-mainnet-14276.bin
../run: 1: ./nix/store/slls7lvg8yfdv9ax8mfw653sxfq49shv-startup: not found
roberto@roberto-870-224:~/Downloads$

Comment: @RobertoBeaumont You might need to see https://forum.cardano.org/t/daedalus-1-0-0-not-installing-on-ubuntu-16-04/32364/2