# Running command before suspend

Tags: bash, scripts, suspend

I've found several posts (e.g., [How do I run commands on suspend/return from suspend?](https://superuser.com/questions/733333/how-do-i-run-commands-on-suspend-return-from-suspend), [How to run a script before suspend?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1328663/how-to-run-a-script-before-suspend), [Script not running on resume/wakeup in Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/775934/script-not-running-on-resume-wakeup-in-ubuntu)) that describe adding a script in `/etc/pm/sleep.d` or `/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d` to execute commands at suspend/resume.  However, I haven't been able to get this to work; the script seems to never execute despite having rx permissions for root.  I went all the way back to simply having the script execute an echo that outputs to a file just to confirm and that nothing happens.  (See script at bottom.)

What I want to accomplish is to have the suspend execute a script that runs rtcwake to implement a wake-up in the early morning for a maintenance script to run.  I cannot just execute the maintenance script from cron since the system is suspended.  So, I need to resume the system at a specific time in advance and then allow the job to execute.

```
#!/bin/bash/
case "${1}" in
  suspend)
    #suspend_actions
    echo "suspend" >> text.out
    ;;
  resume)
    #resume_actions
    echo "resume" >> text.out
    ;;
esac
```

Comment: Use the full path to `text.out`, e.g. `/tmp/text.out`.

Comment: Why not RTCWake the system at 06:00, and schedule the cron job for 06:30?

Comment: @waltinator -- That is exactly what I'm attempting to do.  But the problem I have is that rtcwake is a one time deal (best I can determine).  I can set it for one wakeup (e.g., at 3am) but I can't run it and have it wake up *everyday* at 3am.  And I did try some explicit paths but they didn't change anything.  Scripts in sleep.d run as root so it should be able to write anywhere, yes?