# how i install several programs at one click

Tags: software-installation

I want to install several software at one click
I have all the installation packages on usb and i want to group the together because I need to install them on several laptops

any ideas??

The Sherriff.

Comment: Write a script to do it and save it on the usb drive.

Answer (score 2):

Open a terminal in the directory containing the .deb files.

Now enter the command

```
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

to install all the Debian packages.

Then run `sudo apt install -f` to install any missing dependencies (in case there are any).

**Warning**: If you use this method to install incompatible .deb packages (e.g. if you install packages built for Ubuntu 20.04 in 18.04), that may seriously break the package management system, and you would have to reinstall Ubuntu. However, packages build for the same version of Ubuntu should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple to do. Just write a script.
Example

```
apt install /path/to/gimp.deb && apt install /path/to/gparted.deb && apt install /path/to/kazam.deb
```

save it and make it [executeable](https://askubuntu.com/questions/229589/how-to-make-a-file-e-g-a-sh-script-executable-so-it-can-be-run-from-a-termi). And then run the script as a superuser.

The above script will simply install softwares one by one.

You can write anything you want for installation like dpkg.

Comment: OP has all the .deb files in an USB. This method would try to download them from the internet.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi yeah whatever. By the way, '.deb ' packages can also be installed using apt

Comment: I am not sure if we can use apt to install several .deb packages using wildcards. That is why I used dpkg in the answer.

Comment: We can use wildcard(*) with aptitute :)

Comment: @Technoworld minor edit to your script. If you don't like the change, you can revert it.