# How to run shell script commands manually

Tags: vpn, scripts, chromebook

I'm running Ubuntu on my Samsung ARM Chromebook in chroot via crouton. I'm trying to run Cisco AnyConnect VPN in Ubuntu and ran into an issue. It installs but the daemon won't start. I found a description of the issue here:  https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton/issues/15

So I found the shell script for AnyConnect in /etc/init.d but I'm not smart enough to figure out how to run these commands manually. I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

Here are the contents of the vpnagentd_init file:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# chkconfig: 345 85 25
# description: vpnagentd is used for managing the cisco vpn client datapath.
# processname: vpnagentd



# Source function library.
if [ -e "/etc/init.d/functions" ]; then
  . /etc/init.d/functions
fi

RETVAL=0

start() {
  # If TUN isn't supported by the kernel, try loading the module...
  /sbin/lsmod | grep tun > /dev/null
  if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    /sbin/modprobe tun > /dev/null 2> /dev/null
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
      # check for /dev/net/tun
      [ -c "/dev/net/tun" ] || echo  Warning: Unable to verify that the tun/tap driver is loaded.  Contact your system administrator for assistance.
    fi
  fi

  echo -n $"Starting up Cisco VPN daemon "
  /opt/cisco/vpn/bin/vpnagentd
  RETVAL=$?
  echo
  return $RETVAL
}

stop() {
  echo -n $"Shutting down Cisco VPN daemon "
  killall vpnagentd
  RETVAL=$?
  echo
  return $RETVAL
}

dostatus() {
  status vpnagentd
}

restart() {
  stop
  start
}

# See how we were called.
case "$1" in
  start)
        start
        ;;
  stop)
        stop
        ;;
  restart)
    restart
    ;;
  status)
        dostatus
        ;;
  *)
        echo $"Usage: vpnagent {start|stop|restart|status}"
        exit 1
esac

exit $RETVAL
```

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu. Possible duplicate http://askubuntu.com/questions/38661/how-do-i-run-sh-files-in-terminal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an example, to run the 'start daemon' section, copy the contents of the file between "start(){" and "}" and put it in a text file startScript (as ane example). Use chmod+x startScript to make the script executable, then use ./startScript to run it. The same can be done for the stop and status sections if desired.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Unfortunately I got an error (`Starting up Cisco VPN daemon ./vpnstart: line 12: /opt/cisco/vpn/bin/vpnagentd: cannot execute binary file`) but that's beyond the scope of this question. I appreciate your help.

Comment: No problem. Make sure you check permissions on the binary. You'll also likely need to run your startScript as root (using sudo ./startScript).

Comment: @Splendor I had the same problem trying to run Anyconnect on my Raspberry Pi, which is also an ARM box. Seems the problem is the binaries, like vpnagentd, are compiled for Intel architecture. As far as I can tell Cisco doesn't provide source to compile or an ARM binary, so I'm looking for alternatives. Openconnect sounds promising, but I haven't tried it yet.

Comment: Openconnect did the trick. `sudo apt-get install openconnect` and then [connect](http://www.infradead.org/openconnect/connecting.html) and I'm on my way.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to answer if it is just to run a shell script.

Open terminal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> and type :

```
sudo nautilus
```

Give your password. Browse to location where that script present. Right click on the file. Goto **properties**--> **Permissions**. Give execute permissions by checking on "**Allow executing file as a program**".

Use `cd directory_name` to go to script location. And type `sh vpnagentd_init.sh` to run the script. Hope it will help.