# Commands in script do not run, but in terminal they do

Tags: 12.10, command-line, scripts

My script is as follows:

```
#!/bin/sh

rm -rfv /home/user/Documents/Exercise/*

cp -rfv /home/user/Documents/ExerciseShare/ExerciseFiles/Word/Advanced/ /home/tp3/Documents/Exercise/
```

If i was to run these commands individually via Terminal they run ok. I have put them in a script (as above) and when I attempt to tun the script the Terminal windows flashes for about a second and nothing happens.

My attempts at solutions:

1. Adding `wait` to the end of the script - no luck
2. Right Click Script > Properties > Permissions > Execute - set
3. Attempted to `Run` and `Run in Terminal` - no luck

I am using Ubuntu 12.10 64-bit

Comment: Try to delete ` at the start/finish of script, on the other hand, first you delete a folder and in the next step you copy this folder to another location. Maybe first you want to copy the folder and after content its copied, delete it.

Comment: the ` at the start of the script was just meant to add the code tag here on the forum sorry. I have a specific need to delete first. This code will be modified for different folders and files. So the delete command must come first.

Comment: When you say the Terminal window flashes, what do you mean? How are you running the script? If you're running it by making a Terminal window open just to run it and then close automatically, then what happens when you run your script manually in the terminal, by typing `./script`, replacing `script` with the name of your script. (If that works, then it's *especially* important for you to explain precisely how you're running the script when it doesn't work.)

Comment: see http://askubuntu.com/questions/38661/how-do-i-run-sh-files-in-terminal and http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31760/file-extensions-for-unix-shell-scripts

Comment: The Terminal windows opens as if it is going to do something then closes almost instantly, hence it appears to flash. Here is the error when I run the script from terminal `/home/user/Desktop/copyword.sh`
`bash: /home/user/Desktop/copyword.sh: /bin/sh^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many more hours of tinkering I have found an unlikely answer.

I created a new blank document and added only the two lines I wanted (without the heading of #!/bin/sh) :

```
rm -rfv /home/user/Documents/Exercise/*
cp -rfv /home/user/Documents/ExerciseShare/ExerciseFiles/Word/Advanced/ /home/tp3/Documents/Exercise/
```

I then saved the document, right-click > properties > permissions > execute as program

Bingo!

Thanks to all that helped!

Answer (score 0):

According to your comment, you had introduced an extra carriage return (\r) at the end of your shebang line

```
/bin/sh^M: bad interpreter
```

If you open your original file in vim, you'd see the `^M` character; you could just remove it. Or you could open it in a hex editor such as hexedit, where you'd see an extra `0D`.

Linux newlines are single newline characters (\n, 0x0A), as opposed to Windows newlines which still hark back to the days of typewriters (\r\n, 0x0D 0x0A).