# How can I update Tor browser?

Tags: updates, browser, tor

I downloaded the Tor Browser and when I ran it, I get that it need to be updated.

So I when to the tor website and downloaded the tor bundle and extracted it.

When I double click on `start-tor-browser` it only opened the text file and wouldn't run tor. Even when I opened up the tor browser it still said it needed an update.

I used to run it on Ubuntu 12.04, but since I upgraded to 13.04 it wouldn't.

Is their a command I can use in terminal to start tor or how can i update the tor browser?

Answer (score 2):

**How to update?**

Just download the latest version from [their website](http://www.torproject.us/download/download-easy.html.en).

**How to run it?**

After unzip the file:

1. Grant [*execute* privileges](https://askubuntu.com/q/38661/62483) to the `start-tor-browser` file:

   ```
   chmod +x start-tor-browser
   ```
2. Double click the file
3. If you get a message, click on *Run*

That is all

Comment: would i put this in terminal sudo chmod +x tor-browser_en-US.sh or sudo chmod +x /path/to/tor-browser_en-US.sh? im not exactly sure what to put in :/

Comment: First: open a terminal. Second: go to your unzipped folder (`cd tor-browser_en-US`) Third: grant privileges to the `start-tor-browser` file

Comment: I have no idea how to grant permission to the file i've tried the things that was said on the "executive privileges" link but nothing worked so far i extracted the file and i right click on the file and when to permissions but i can't figure the rest of it out :/

Comment: Are you kidding me right? To grant permissions: **1º** *right click* on the file **2º** go to *Permissions* label **3º** [enable *Allow executing file as program*](http://i.stack.imgur.com/JuFMt.png)

Comment: Yea i did that but when i double clicked on it, it only opened in text :/ and i clicked on the tor browser just in case i was susposed to click on it to run tor but it said it needs an up date :/ (I have the lastest bundle)

Comment: It says command not found :/

Comment: Still not doing anything D:

Comment: Would it help if i post screen shots?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a very advanced user, but I always run tor from the terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T).
Go to the directory where you unpacked it using the cd and ls commands and then ./start-tor-browser

That's how I do it and it works very well.