# Where do I put this code to install Absynth 5?

Tags: scripts

I want to install absynth 5 on my computer. I found this code, here it is.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Date : (2013-02-01)
# Last revision : (2013-02-01)
# Distribution used to test : Kubuntu 12.04 LTS
# Author : DJYoshaBYD
# Licence : GPLv3
# PlayOnLinux: 4.1.9

# CHANGELOG
# [SuperPlumus] (2013-06-17 19-35)
#   Update gettext message


[ "$PLAYONLINUX" = "" ] && exit 0
source "$PLAYONLINUX/lib/sources"

PREFIX="Absynth5"
WINEVERSION="1.3.0"
TITLE="Absynth 5"
EDITOR="Native Instruments"
GAME_URL="http://www.native-instruments.com"
AUTHOR="DJYoshaBYD"

#Initialization
POL_GetSetupImages "http://files.playonlinux.com/resources/setups/$PREFIX/top.jpg" "http://files.playonlinux.com/resources/setups/$PREFIX/left.jpg" "$TITLE"
POL_SetupWindow_Init

POL_Debug_Init

# Presentation
POL_SetupWindow_presentation "$TITLE" "$EDITOR" "$GAME_URL" "$AUTHOR" "$PREFIX"

# Create Prefix
POL_SetupWindow_browse "$(eval_gettext 'Please select the setup file to run')" "$TITLE"
POL_System_SetArch "x86"
POL_Wine_SelectPrefix "$PREFIX"
POL_Wine_PrefixCreate "$WINEVERSION"

#Dependencies

# Configuration
Set_OS "winxp"
Set_SoundDriver "alsa"

# Installation
POL_Wine_WaitBefore "$TITLE"
GC_DONT_GC=1 POL_Wine "$APP_ANSWER"
POL_Wine_WaitExit "$TITLE"

# Create Shortcuts
POL_Shortcut "Absynth\ 5.exe" "$TITLE"

POL_SetupWindow_message "$(eval_gettext 'NOTICE: For low-latency audio, look into WineASIO.')" "$TITLE"

POL_SetupWindow_Close
exit 0
```

But I think it is supposed to go somewhere other than the Terminal because in the terminal after typing #!/bin/bash I still get a $ sign. Thank you in advance for all of your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are not commands that should be entered on the command line. When you see text with "#!" at the start of the first line, it indicates that it is a script. You should put the text in a file and run it all at once.

Open your text editor, and paste the code into a new file. Save the file to "absynth5.sh".

Now, use one of the answers presented here to run the script:

[How do I run .sh files?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38661/how-do-i-run-sh-files-in-terminal)