# Permission denied when running .sh scripts

Tags: 12.04

```
./geany_run_script.sh: 5: ./geany_run_script.sh: ./Area_circumference: Permission denied
```

`program exited with code: 126`. This problem always occur when I try to execute my code. What might be the solution?

Comment: `Permission denied` error are occurs only if you don't have enough privilege to access that file.

Comment: How can I change the permissions

Comment: Where do I do that please give me a shot example

Comment: When I do that it tells me this chmod: cannot access `geany_run_script.sh': No such file or directory. Should I run it from the terminal or what?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I run .sh files in Terminal?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/38661/how-do-i-run-sh-files-in-terminal)

Answer (score 249, accepted):

Here's a link which explains about [Changing file permission (and ownership)](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions)

If you want to skip these (for now of course), you can create a directory/folder in your user-home directory and work on your `C` programmes (or others) there.

---

You can open the terminal (press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>) and `cd` to the target directory:

```
cd /path/to/target
```

To give the file "the_file_name" execute permission (if the file-system allows you with the RW rights):

```
chmod +x the_file_name
```

Comment: How can I change the permissions any examples

Comment: The problem how can I do that?I am a new Ubuntu user I recently switched from windows.

Comment: ..what's your working directory ie. what's the location of your source code file? ..do you have some experience with windows CLI?

Comment: @wkhwilo-012, see if that helps and please don't hesitate to ask more..

Comment: @wkhwilo-012, please copy your executable file `Area_circumference` and paste it (the file path will be pasted) to update your question's body...

Comment: Thank you @precise. I had a permission issue with my deploy.sh script and your answer fixed my issue.  I just gave permission to my *deploy.sh* file by going to the path and using 'chmod +x *deploy.sh*' --- Now it works perfectly! Thanks

Comment: executable even for the public?

Answer (score 47):

You need to give `execute` and `read` permissions. Follow this:

```
chmod u+r+x filename.sh

./filename.sh
```

When we make a new script file then by default it has read and write permission.
But if we want to execute them, then we should give execute permission as shown above.

> Execution bit alone is not enough for shell scripts, one must be able to read the file as well to execute it (contrary to binaries which only need the execute permission bit)

Comment: u (user) +rx (add read and execute permissions)

Comment: Indeed, the second `plus` may be omitted - `u+rx`.

Answer (score 4):

Or you can excute it with your shell directly(or other shell versions), if you don't want to change the permission.

```
$ bash filename.sh
```

Comment: How does this work?

Comment: @RobBell bash a type of shell program used to interpret the bash script. Its synopsis is `bash [options] [command_string | file]`, so it is possible we execute one command like this `echo "echo hello world" | bash` or `bash script.sh`, because we don't excute script with `./` so  it is even no need to add `#!/bin/bash`(specify the interpreter) in the script .  (more specifically, script.sh is just a file to be read by the interpreter bash in the command string `bash script.sh`)

Comment: what I meant is how does this circumvent the security constraints?

Comment: @RobBell I am not sure if I could convince you with the following explanation. I don't think it is a security violation, although the script even can modify itself's  provilege in its contents. When we execute a readable script like this, it just like executing its contents one by one in the terminal.

Answer (score 2):

Open your terminal application by pressing `CTRL` + `ALT` + `T` or with the apposite shortcut on the graphical enviroment (like `Terminal` or `xTerm`).
In the uniform window which appears on the screen you'll see a blinking character, it's the `terminal cursor`: simply click on the window and write to enter text (typically commands) and press `ENTER` to confirm the input.
Before the cursor there is always listed your current position on the file system from the `root directory` ("/") and your home (where your personal files are) is called "~".
To change directory/folder use `cd EXISTENTFOLDER` (replace EXISTENTFOLDER with the folder name); if you feel lost, simply type `cd` to return to your home directory in a blink!
Now **let's solve your problem**:

1. Use the `cd` command to find the directory with your source code. Use `TAB` to help you. If you execute `ls -lh`, you'll see a list of possible paths to follow and files to execute.
2. When you've find the blocked file execute `chmod +x FILENAME` (replace FILENAME with the name of your source code file).
3. If you have multiple blocked files execute `chmod +x *` to unlock all files in the current directory. **Never chmod +x dangerous or insecure files**.
4. Execute `./FILENAME YOUREVENTUALARGUMENTS` to execute your executable file.
5. Remember that if your compiled program tries to read/write outside your home directory you'll need to execute it as `root` by using `sudo ./FILENAME YOUREVENTUALARGUMENTS`.

If you want to have a manual for a command execute `man COMMAND` (replace COMMAND with the exact command name, Linux is case sensitive).

Some shells have an `Open terminal here` command to simplify your life, search for it in the future and remember that the command shell can be your best friend, if you use it well. :-D

It's all. If you need more help comment under here.
If I'm helping you press the UP arrow on the left; if you solve mark this answer as best answer.

Have a nice experience on Linux & Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now I can work under the home directory. The operation you asked me earlier cannot be permitted. It says I have no permission but thanks anyway for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

For the rest of us where the issue *isn't* caused by the execute bit not being set, @Avinash-Raj put it best:

> `Permission denied` error are occurs only if you don't have enough privilege to access that file.

In my case, it was root lacking permission to access a fuse-based mount or mounted fs is set to `noexec`.. It really does boil down to whoever the script is run under lacking the necessary permissions to access or run the script.

To confirm that, use `findmnt --target <filepath>`

```
TARGET SOURCE FSTYPE OPTIONS
/tmp   tmpfs  tmpfs  rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,size=1024k,inode64
                                    #^^^^^^
```

I'm leaving this obvious/trivial answer here for my fellow fuse users to whom google will absolutely refuse to suggest any solution other than setting the execute bit.

Comment: See also https://askubuntu.com/a/1346745/633466