# Bash Script Permission Denied when tying to run

Tags: command-line, bash, permissions, scripts

I can't run my Bash script, execution permission is always denied.

I modified my files with command for example:

```
chmod u+x bash_script1.sh
```

and obtained the following after:

```
-rwxr--r-- 1 user group 1947 Jun 18 16:04 bash_script1.sh
-rwxr--r-- 1 user group 2430 Jun 18 15:59 bash_script2.sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 user group    1 Jun 18 10:57 runs.txt
```

However, I continue to get the following error when running from command line:

Comand:

```
./bash_script1.sh
```

Error:

```
-sh: ./bash_script1.sh: Permission denied
```

When I run the following command below, I don't get the error but I don't want to use bash to run my script:

```
bash bash_script1.sh
```

`#!/usr/bin/env bash` is placed at my heading.

Comment: You only gave execute permission to `user` - are you actually logged in as `user` when you try this? what is the output of the `id` command? what is the exact command that produces the error `-sh: ./bash_script1.sh: Permission denied`?

Comment: Yes, it is exactly that error that I get when trying to run `./file_script1.sh` in command line. The output is as follows: `uid=19979(user) gid=867800079(group) groups=867800079(group),11226(research),11765(omics)`

Comment: I just gave permission to all users to execute chmod uga+rwx file.sh and it still gives me the permission denied error....

Comment: OK so the only other cause I can think of is that the filesystem it's stored on is mounted with the `noexec` option - check with `findmnt -T .` (run from the directory that contains the script)

Comment: `/home  /dev/md126p2 xfs    rw,noexec,relatime,attr2,inode64,noquota` this is what I get after. How can I change this? or do I have to ask my sysadmin?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As we can see from the output of `findmnt -T .`, the filesystem on which the script is stored is mounted with the `noexec` option. This prevents scripts (as well as binary executables) from being executed directly, whereas `bash bash_script1.sh` still works because the `bash` executable is stored elsewhere and only needs to *read* the script.

To modify the behavior temporarily you can use the `mount` command:

```
sudo mount -o remount,exec /home
```

To make the change persistent, you will need to modify your `/etc/fstab` file and remove the `noexec` mount option for this block device.

Comment: this is all definitely new to me, so I will have to look into it deeper for sure. unfortunately I do not have sudo rights thus will have to reach out to my sysadmin for more guidance. Thank you so much at least for the clarification :D

Comment: @Joe_Informatics you're welcome - tbh I was slightly surprised that the `noexec` option has this effect on scripts (not only binary executables) - the `mount` man page just says `noexec Do not permit direct execution of any binaries on the mounted filesystem.`. But I confirmed the behavior on my own system, and it's discussed in more detail here for example [Executing a bash script or a c binary on a file system with noexec option](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/490402/executing-a-bash-script-or-a-c-binary-on-a-file-system-with-noexec-option)

Comment: yeah this is definitely new to me, but nice to know the root of the problem. Will take a look at url provided :D