# perl script wont run unless I use perl prefix

Tags: permissions, scripts, 22.04, perl

I have a weird problem trying to run a simple perl script on ubuntu 22.04.

test.pl content:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
print "Hello\n";
```

output of `which perl` command:

```
/usr/bin/perl
```

I used to run scripts with just their path, but now I get `permission denied` when doing so, unless I use the `perl` prefix.

```
distcc@a172-24-178-137:~$ ./test.pl
bash: ./test.pl: Permission denied
distcc@a172-24-178-137:~$ perl ./test.pl
Hello
```

Permissions look fine to me:

```
distcc@a172-24-178-137:~$ ls -l test.pl
-rwxr-xr-x 1 distcc staff 33 Feb  6 17:07 test.pl
```

what is causing the problem?

Comment: I wonder if an invisible character has snuck into the shebang line. Can you show us the output from `hexdump -C test.pl` please.

Comment: The size of the file (33 bytes) matches the clean version I made locally. There's no invisible character.  That error looks like this: `bash: ./test.pl: /usr/bin/perl^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory`

Comment: A related post from the sidebar seems to have the answer. Perhaps [the filesystem is mounted with 'noexec'](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1346733/bash-script-permission-denied-when-tying-to-run).

Comment: @Kyle you are right, that was the case. a bit different on 22.04 but same root cause.