# Unable to execute .sh files in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: scripts

I am unable to run .sh file in Ubuntu 14.04. The same file was executing in earlier version 12.xx. After upgrading to 14.04, this file stopped running. How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Did your script have execute permissions http://askubuntu.com/a/38666/265974 ? What is the content of the script?

Comment: How are you trying to execute script: using the command line or from the graphical interface? What do you get when you try to execute?

Comment: Impossible to say --- what means "stopped  running"? Could be that the script rely on a command or interface which is not here anymore. Try to run the script in a terminal and edit your answer with the output.

Comment: I am assuming you already have this since it worked earlier, but please cross check to see you have "#!/bin/sh" as your first line.

Answer (score 7):

All that you need to do is set default action here `File Manager > Edit > Preferences > Behaviour` for`Executable Text Files`. In Ubuntu 14.04 it is set to `View Executable Files when they are opened`

Answer (score 3):

You can check whether or not the script is executable by doing something like:

```
$ ls -l nameoffile
```

replacing `nameoffile` with the name of the script. The output will look like:

```
-rwxr-xr-x  1 users users 848101 Mar 12 11:22 configure
```

The last `x` in the first column, means that this file is an executable. If this `x` is missing, it means that the file is not executable. You can easily fix this. To make a script executable, you can execute:

```
chmod +x /path/to/nameofscript.sh
```

After that to execute it from the command line, you can do:

```
./path/to/nameofscript
```

Xubu-tur referenced a very good explanation for doing this from a graphical environment.

Comment: I don't know that install-sh is supposed to do. But looking at the output my guess is that it wants some kind of input.