# "Run In Terminal" message doesn't appear

Tags: 14.04, command-line, nautilus, .sh

I'm trying to execute a **.sh** file, but its opening in *gedit*. I permitted it to be "executed as program", but it's still not working. I'm on a machine running Ubuntu 14.04LTS.

Comment: Can you find "Run in terminal" in the right click menu, under "Open with..." or so?

Comment: Nope. Terminal isnt in the list.

Comment: Maybe I should try Linux Mint, Ubuntu is too slow when launching programs

Comment: Maybe, but that's a different question (Lubuntu and Xubuntu are other 'fast' options); Do you know what is slow? If it's really starting programs - do you have limited RAM? (Anyway, just some ideas, but that does not belong to this question)

Comment: I think 3GB are enough...

Comment: Should be enough - except it's used up by a misbehaving program. Still, it's the wrong place for this discussion. I did not see an obvious duplicate question, so you could ask another one regarding slow program start.

Comment: Nah, everybody knows Unity is very demanding and slow... Gonna change to mint asap

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Setting the "executed as program" permission is not enough as there's a global Nautilus preference that alter the behavior when you click on an executable text file.

Open the Nautilus Preferences (Edit -> Preferences) and select the Behavior tab:

[image]

Select the "Ask each time" option to get the following popup when you click on your `.sh` files:

[image]