# Linux equivalent for «cmd /C start "Title" "C:\Folder\file.bat"»

Tags: command-line, bash, java

I have a Java program that runs a batch file on Windows with `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` using the following command:

```
cmd /C start "Title" "C:\Folder\file.bat"
```

The Java program ends quickly since **`cmd /C`** carries out the command and then terminates <sup>**(1)**</sup> and **`start "Title" "C:\Folder\file.bat"`** *starts* the batch script <sup>**(2)**</sup>. Thus the process (the batch file) will continue running **independently**.

Now, suppose that I have an shell script (e.g. **`file.sh`**), which I want to launch from Java and has a similar behavior. How could it be the equivalent command <sup>**(3)**</sup> in Linux?

---

*Notes*

1. See [CMD.exe (Command Shell) | Windows CMD | SS64.com](http://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html)
2. See [Start - Start a program | Windows CMD | SS64.com](http://ss64.com/nt/start.html)
3. The title (**`"Title"`**) is not required.

Comment: we have SO MANY ways to execute a file in linux. but perhaps sharing the contents of your .bat file would be more lucrative.  the path, C:\ doesnt exist, youll change that to the path in linux. ~/<script> you could call a shell. bash <script-name>
or do ./<script-name> if it is executable (bit set). Dont be confussed, we have bash scripts, those work great, batch scripts, ... not so much

Comment: @j0h I have edited the question. The content of the script can be anything. However, I am interested in the command to launch it with a similar behavior.

Comment: The question effectively is a duplicate of this: http://askubuntu.com/q/38661/295286  Once bounty expires, it should be voted to be closed

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy - the item you link is about running scripts from the desktop. OP asks about launching processes from within Java. Not a duplicate?

Comment: @taifwa  OP knows how to launch process from Java program  -
 they already mention `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()`, and Java being cross-platform language would use same method to launch a program.  The post isn't about running scripts form desktop either - it's running scripts in general, and the key to that making script executable with `chmod +x` and giving path to script or at least having script live in one of the directories that belong to `PATH` variable.  Whether or not it's form Java is irrelevant. These steps are required

Answer (score 5):

The way to launch a script is to give its path:

```
/path/to/script.sh
```

To have it continue if the parent process exits, you can just launch it in the background by appending `&`:

```
/path/to/script.sh &
```

So, if you have, for example, one script calling another like so:

```
#!/bin/bash
script2.sh &
```

You could run `script1.sh` which will call `script2.sh` and, because it is sent to the background, exit immediately.

Answer (score 1):

You have many options, the more interesting are these:

- If it's for Ubuntu, you can use `gnome-terminal`:

  ```
  gnome-terminal -c "/home/$USER/file.sh" -t "Title"
  ```

  or:

  ```
  gnome-terminal -- "/home/$USER/file.sh" -t "Title"
  ```
- If do you want to make it compatible with most linux, you can use `xterm`:

  ```
  xterm -T "Title" -e "/home/$USER/file.sh"
  ```

The path is `/home/$USER/file.sh` (Windows 7 equivalent: `C:\Users\%UserProfile%\file.bat`)

The `file.sh` contents may be something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "In a World without Walls nor Fences, the people don't need Windows and Gates"
sleep 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Various ways to execute a script in Linux:
my arbitrary script name is foo.bat

ex1:`$bash foo.bat`

ex2:`$./foo.bat`

ex3:`$echo $(~/Desktop/foo.bat)`

ex4:`~/Desktop/foo.bat`

ex5:$ /path/to/shell/script/foo.bat

```
ex1: this is is just a regular file at this point, we execute it with bash
ex2: we have marked foo.bat as executable. ($chmod +x foo.bat)
ex3: Command substitution 
ex4: execute using "``"
ex5: we us the path to the executable.
```

These are the most common.
I would avoid calling things like gnome-terminal, and xterm. These are less common shells compared to things like bash, and sh.
For example I use Ubuntu mate. I have neither xterm nor gnome-terminal. But, I do have bash, and sh. as does nearly ever other person running Linux / mac osx.

You may appreciate this tutorial on script execution [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_01.html)

the script foo.bat does this:

```
$ ./foo.bat
Having a bash ./foo.bat
```

where its contents are:

```
$ cat foo.bat 
#!/bin/bash
echo -e "Having a bash" $0
```

I think the use of $0 can give you the title functionality you may desire.
Many more possibilities exist.

Comment: gnome-terminal and xterm are not shells themselves, rather they're terminal emulators which run a shell. bash is a shell. zsh is a shell. ksh is a shell.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, you want to run an external command from within Java, and have the Java process continue (asynchronously) whilst that external command continues to run too?

Here's a little test I whipped up:

```
[tai@flenux runproc ] $ ls
filecreator.sh  ProcRunner.class  ProcRunner.java

[tai@flenux runproc ] $ cat filecreator.sh 
touch newfile

[tai@flenux runproc ] $ cat ProcRunner.java 

public class ProcRunner {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec(args);
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            System.out.println("Done");
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.toString() );
        }
    }
}

[tai@flenux runproc ] $ java ProcRunner bash filecreator.sh 
Done

[tai@flenux runproc ] $ ls
filecreator.sh  newfile  ProcRunner.class  ProcRunner.java

[tai@flenux runproc ] $
```

Java successfully execs the program (which simply creates the "newfile" file) ; it also continues on its own merry way to print the Done message after calling the exec.

If you wanted a terminal window to open too, prefix the call string

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(["gnome-terminal", "-e"]+args);
```

So to answer your question, it looks like you would just call the method you specified. Are you getting a different behaviour?