# Bash script doesn't run from nautilus, but does run from terminal

Tags: bash, nautilus, scripts, shared-library

Before I add more detail to my question, I have to say something very important:

**Yes, my script has "Allow executing file as program" turned on.**

#### The question itself:

For programming reasons (shared libraries), I can't execute my program just from the executable, because I need to access `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` before executing the program. I created this script to do this (baring in mind this is my first time ever writing a script):

```
#!/bin/bash
#Get the current directory and append the SO's location
currentDir=$(pwd)'/libs/'

#Change the library path
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$currentDir

#Run the program
./program
```

After running this from the terminal I thought that it has worked, there were no errors and the program didn't complain about shared libraries. But unfortunately, if I try to double-click the `.sh` file from Nautilus, nothing happens. The worst part as well, is that since I'm running it from the GUI, I have no idea what error it is getting. I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 and the executable is a C++ program using the SFML libraries (Yes I could just have the dependencies, but SFML isn't commonly installed on Linux computers, and this is besides the point).

Comment: Add the line `notify-send $LD_LIBRARY_PATH` below the line `export…` and test it again.

Comment: @JacobVlijm Do you know how I can cd to the correct directory, even if it has a spaces? Because when I try to call the script it cuts off at any space

Comment: @A.B. No difference, same output in terminal, same lack of anything in nautilus

Comment: No notification? Nothing?

Comment: Me? `cd "your path even with spaces"`

Comment: @A.B. Nothing. According to the man page it should create a notification but no, nothing

Comment: But if there's no output via libnotify, something other is wrong

Comment: @A.B. I reinstalled notify-send, so I can see the notification when in the terminal, but I get nothing in the nautilus

Comment: Place a notify at the second line, below the she-bang.

Comment: @A.B. Again, nothing, I'm starting to think it's not to do with the script's contents...

Comment: What says `gsettings get org.gnome.nautilus.preferences executable-text-activation`

Comment: @A.B. 'display'

Comment: `gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.preferences executable-text-activation ask`

Comment: @A.B. That fixes it!

Comment: Sure, I now. That was simple =)

Comment: Why not simply `LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$PWD/libs" ./program`? No need for subshells or intermediary variables.

Comment: @DavidFoerster As I mentioned, its my first time writing a bash script, and I'd prefer for it to be readable and expandable (at the time I thought I'd need to add more code to fix the issue), and I don't care about size since I'm not submitting it to [Code Golf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) ;)

Comment: Good point. In that case, I hope you could still learn something from my comment, for instance, about the automatic shell variable `PWD` and prefixing commands with environment variables.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I run .sh files in Terminal?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/38661/how-do-i-run-sh-files-in-terminal). For how to run .sh files in nautilus see the answer by imjustmatthew.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The property <kbd>Allow executing file as program</kbd> is not enough.

Change the settings in Nautilus Preferences

[image]

---

or via terminal:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.preferences executable-text-activation ask
```

Comment: When you put a screen shot which of those settings do you exactly mean?