# How to make a .sh file that installs something?

Tags: scripts

I want to make a .sh file that installs a package. Do I have to write this this?:

```
#!/bin/sh
# start a terminal session in the background

sudo apt-get install thepackage

exit 0
```

Comment: http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_writing_shell_scripts.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most packages can be installed using a script like yours.  You do need to answer the question "install (Y/n)" that `apt-get` asks:

`sudo apt-get install -y <packagename>`

will work for all but a few packages that open up a terminal during configuration, such as the `ttf-mscorefonts-installer`

Look through the link sent in the comment by @bodhi.zazen, particularly the first chapter.  There are some basic bits about script files you are missing.

Comment: I downloaded an .sh file to install an application in Ubuntu.  Do I changed the folder to the download terminal then  follow your instructions?  I do not want the application installed in the Download folder.

Comment: @JoseEnriqueCalderon Please see [https://askubuntu.com/questions/38661/how-do-i-run-sh-files](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38661/how-do-i-run-sh-files)