# Running a .sh script

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I had a software developed. And now my developer is no longer working with me. I have about 40 users on this, and it seems this thing is ran manually. Yet it was working for the users when they used their copy of it. Im so lost. Any help much appreciated.

**His instructions say this:**

> script_run_scrapers.sh: bash script for run the ranks scrapers
>   (googlerank, googlevideorank and youtuberank) via wget
>
> sample for run 300 scrapers
>
> ```
> ./script_run_scrapers.sh 300 10
> ```

This is the code in the script:

```
max=$1
maxy=$2
while [ 1 ] ; do
    x=`ps -Af | grep wget | grep -c "path_to_web"`;
    echo $x;
    if [ $x -lt $max ] ; then
        r=$RANDOM;
        #echo $r;
        i=1;
        y=$(( $max - $x ));
        while [ $i -le $y ] ; do
            wget -O /dev/null -o /dev/null "http://127.0.0.1/path_to_web/googlescraper.php?max=$maxy"  2>&1 &
            i=$(( $i + 1 ));
        done;
    fi;
    sleep 5s;
done;
```

[image]

Comment: What happens when you try to run the script? When you `cd` into the directory where the script is and then run `./script_run_scrapers.sh 300 10` in a terminal window, what shows on the screen?

Comment: What does the screenshot have to do with anything?

Comment: What is your question? Do you want to know how to run you shell-script? Then https://askubuntu.com/questions/38661/how-do-i-run-sh-files could help you. `chmod +x` needs the filename as additional argument (as it is telling you, that it needs one more argument).

Comment: Because that is as far as I have got with this.

Comment: I havent been able to run the script. I am very new to this, just trying to get it to work again. My dev wont help me.

Answer (score 1):

In order to make your script executable, you need to use chmod +x and specify the file you are modifying.

So

```
chmod +x script_run_scrapers.sh
```

As it stands you have just run

```
chmod +x
```

but not specified the file that is to be made executable.

You have also typed cd to change directory, but have not specified where you want to change directory to. For example :

```
cd /home/victor
```

will change directory to /home/victor/

I think what you are wanting to do is change into the directory that holds your script, then modify the permissions of your script so that is is executable, then execute it ?

Lets assume your script is in the directory /home/victor/

```
cd /home/victor/

chmod +x script_run_scrapers.sh
```

That only has to be done once, then all you have to do is execute it

```
./script_run_scrapers.sh 300 10
```

To check the current permission of the file, use ls -la

```
ls -la script_run_scrapers.sh
```

Comment: root@LAPTOP-RG1ECSPS:~# cd
root@LAPTOP-RG1ECSPS:~# chmod +x
chmod: missing operand after ‘+x’
Try 'chmod --help' for more information.
root@LAPTOP-RG1ECSPS:~# chmod +x script_run_scrapers.sh
chmod: cannot access ‘script_run_scrapers.sh’: No such file or directory
root@LAPTOP-RG1ECSPS:~#

Comment: Like this  cd C:\Users\Randy James\Desktop\

chmod +x script_run_scrapers.sh

Comment: root@LAPTOP-RG1ECSPS:~# cd C:\Users\Randy James\Desktop\
> chmod +x script_run_scrapers.sh
bash: cd: C:UsersRandy: No such file or directory
root@LAPTOP-RG1ECSPS:~# cd desktop
bash: cd: desktop: No such file or directory
root@LAPTOP-RG1ECSPS:~# cd

Comment: cd C:\Users\Randy James\Desktop\ . This is a Windows directory structure, in linux you dont specify a drive letter, don't use the colon and the slashes are the other way. For example cd /home/victor/

Comment: like this? cd C/Users/Randy James/Desktop/

Comment: cd /Users/Randy James/Desktop/

Comment: root@LAPTOP-RG1ECSPS:~# cd /users/randy james/desktop/
bash: cd: /users/randy: No such file or directory

Comment: Will the code change if i am using bash on ubuntu on windows?

Comment: root@LAPTOP-RG1ECSPS:~# cd /mnt/c
root@LAPTOP-RG1ECSPS:/mnt/c# chmod +x script_run_scrapers.sh
root@LAPTOP-RG1ECSPS:/mnt/c# ./script_run_scrapers.sh 300 10
0
0

Comment: I did something!!

Comment: 21 packages can be updated.
12 updates are security updates.
root@LAPTOP-RG1ECSPS:~# cd /mnt/c/
root@LAPTOP-RG1ECSPS:/mnt/c# ./script_run_scrapers.sh 300 10
0
151
300
300
300
300
300
300
300
300

Comment: Your using bash on Ubuntu in windows ? Well you never said that ....

Comment: Yes do you know what the developer meant with this part of the code./script_run_scrapers.sh 300 10 the 300 10 represent what? Its now making my software time out.

Comment: So have you now got the script running ? Did you succesfully make it executable using chmod and get it running ? Assuming that you did, the first 2 lines of the code assign values to the variables 'max' and 'maxy'. In this case, 'max'=300 and 'maxy'=10. Those values are used while iterating through your loop.

Comment: What is it, exactly, that you want to achieve ? What results are you expecting this code to produce ? I'm no bash expert, but the code looks like it is running a php script on the localhost (googlescraper.php). Does that script exist ? On a side note, why has your dev left ? (Think you might need to buy him/her a beer or get another dev in).

Comment: I am running the script on my local machine when I believe it must be run through my server using bash. Thanks for the tip about maxy, and max. I added those into the script and it just produced 0's. My developer left because he became unresponsive, and left me hanging on the project. I have around 40 beta users on this software.

Comment: And have been trying to get it up and running for a few months now. It is a tool that scrapes the web for videos positions in google, google video, and youtube. The selling point is that it does not need manual keyword entry, as all you have to do is input a channel and it gets the positions. Ive been through 5 developers from freelancer, and they cant fix the issue. So I am learning how to do it myself. I contacted hostgator. And will be trying this next. http://support.hostgator.com/articles/hosting-guide/lets-get-started/how-do-i-get-and-use-ssh-access

Comment: Not sure what you added into the script as Maxy and max are already there. All things considered I am going to gracefully bow out and suggest that you get a new dev in or your old dev back. Sorry I can't help.