# How to install AMD C-60 tweaking script for Linux

Tags: software-installation, make, amd-processor

I am a new user running Lubuntu 64-bit alternate. My computer has an AMD C-60 CPU.

How to install [AMD C-60 tweaking script for Linux](https://github.com/wsdfhjxc/c60-tweak)?

Comment: It's just a script, you don't need to install anything. Just download the `.sh` file, make sure that it is executable and follow the usage instructions from the README.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I run .sh files?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38661/how-do-i-run-sh-files)

Comment: But it says it needs undervolt , under the requirements.

Comment: so your question is how to install `undervolt` ? Then, you should first read the README file that comes packaged with the `undervolt.tar.gz`, this describes how to install it. And if you have problems with that, you can ask ...

Comment: @RoVo The answers in that duplicate link aren't sufficient to answer this question. It's an exact match of about 10% of my answer. That's a very low standard for defining an exact match. That link duplicates Step 9 in my answer and then the OP would have to guess about whatever is in Steps 1-8.

Comment: I disagree. The question does not include how to install the dependencies, so the duplicate fits just fine. You could say that it implicitly include it, but then I'd ask OP what he tried and where he failed as I pointed out in my previous comment. Because the undervolt package includes a README and I don't think we need to duplicate READMEs with answers on askubuntu.

Comment: Anyways, as you wrote a nice answer it might be worth leaving it open ;-)

Answer (score 1):

1. Download undervolt from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/undervolt/).
2. Extract the contents of undervolt-0.4.tgz with Archive Manager or change directories using `cd` to the directory containing undervolt-0.4.tgz and run the following command.

   ```
   tar xzf undervolt-0.4.tgz
   ```
3. Open the terminal and change directories using `cd` to the undervolt-0.4 directory.
4. Run the following commands to make undervolt:

   ```
   sudo apt install make
   make
   ```
5. Copy the file named *undervolt* into a bin or sbin directory.

   ```
   sudo cp undervolt /usr/local/sbin
   ```
6. Information about undervolt usage is in the README.fr file.
7. Download c60-tweak-master.zip from [here](https://github.com/wsdfhjxc/c60-tweak) and extract the contents of c60-tweak-master.zip. Change directories using `cd` to the directory containing c60-tweak-master.zip and run the following commands.

   ```
   sudo apt install unzip   
   unzip c60-tweak-master.zip
   ```
8. Change directories using `cd` to the c60-tweak-master directory.
9. Execute the script in a terminal with `sudo ./c60-tweak.sh` and follow the on-screen instructions.

Answer (score 0):

I was searching and trying a few ways, undervolt and c60-tweak-master aren't working under the current Ubuntu / xUbuntu LTS release 18.04 (in my case). The performance of this cpu without tweaking it is awful (fixed between 0.8 and 1 GHz), I'm running a nextcloud server on it.

So I found this one: https://github.com/johkra/amdmsrtweaker-lnx
1. Download the amdmsrt-amd64.zip for 64 bit 
2. Make sure the needed kernel modules are loaded (just google to make it permanent after reboot): 
sudo modprobe msr
sudo modprobe cpuid

3. Unzip & run amdmsrt-amd64 as root.
4. With this you can undervolt and overclock the cpu to its full potential, just like under windows with brazostweaker.

My stable settings with slight undervolt for the AMD C60 cpu are this (1.3GHz,1.3GHz,1GHz):
home/amdmsrt-amd64 P0=13.3334@1.125 P1=13.3334@1.125 P2=10@1.1 P3=@1.0

The cpu load on the nextcloud "server" changed to the following with 5 parallel downloads:
Without: ~4.0
With: ~1.25 +-0.25

Hope this helps some people because for me its pretty useful :-)