# Why doesn't this bash script run as "sh runserver" recognize the "source" command?

Tags: command-line, bash, source

I want to make a file which will run 2 command.

One will activate a virtual enviroment and after that, second command will run a server.

My file is called "runserver" and it looks like these:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Activating virtual enviroment"
source odoo-venv/bin/activate
echo "Running Odoo server"
./odoo12/odoo-bin --config=/etc/odoo12.conf
```

When I run this file with

```
sh runserver
```

It show the following error:

```
Activating virtual enviroment...
runserver: 3: source: not found
Running Odoo server...
...
```

It seems that my bash file is not recognizing the source command, how can I fix this?

Comment: `source` is a non-portable alias to `.`

Comment: Why are you running your script with `sh runserver` and not `./runserver`?

Comment: @Colin'tHart Perhaps OP has not made it executable? [How do I run .sh scripts?](https://askubuntu.com/q/38661/250300)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`sh` doesn't run your script in `bash` but in `dash` which doesn't support `source`. Use `.` instead:

```
. odoo-venv/bin/activate
```

or run the script with bash:

```
/bin/bash runserver
```

See also [a similar question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13702425/1030675).

Comment: or `sh -c ./runserver`

Comment: @bac0n: Calling one shell to call another shell? Possible but not quite efficient.

Comment: Or just `./runserver`.